# Reverse Polish notation

Tags: code-golf, math

You must evaluate a string written in [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and output the result.

The program must accept an input and return the output. For programming languages that do not have functions to receive input/output, you can assume functions like readLine/print.

You are not allowed to use any kind of "eval" in the program.

Numbers and operators are separated by one **or more** spaces.

You must support at least the +, -, * and / operators.

You need to add support to negative numbers (for example, `-4` is not the same thing as `0 4 -`) and floating point numbers.

**You can assume the input is valid and follows the rules above**

### Test Cases

Input:

```
-4 5 +
```

Output:

```
1
```

---

Input:

```
5 2 /
```

Output:

```
2.5
```

---

Input:

```
5 2.5 /
```

Output:

```
2
```

---

Input:

```
5 1 2 + 4 * 3 - +
```

Output:

```
14
```

---

Input:

```
4 2 5 * + 1 3 2 * + /
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: It's a shame no eval is allowed, otherwise the GolfScript solution is 1 character: `~`. :-P

Comment: That's why it's not allowed :-P, this question on StackOverflow received a 4 chars answer with dc.

Comment: Can I use `eval` to parse numbers only?

Comment: @SHiNKiROU: Which language requires you to use `eval` to parse numbers? It sounds quite broken. (GolfScript is one such language, as far as I'm aware. I think it's broken too.)

Comment: How is -4 not the same as 0 4 - ?

Comment: @Chris: Floating-point numbers are required as well, which rules out Golfscript too. And batch files. And Brainfuck. Unless you reimplement fp support in those which is probably not suitable for a golf task :-)

Comment: What happens when the stack isn't reduced to one element in the end? Still output only the first element? Output the whole stack? Undefined?

Comment: I think eval should be ok if it were just to convert strings to numbers. eg. in python `eval(s)` is better than `float(s)`

Comment: Can we assume the input is fully evaluable? So it won't, for example, be "5 3 8 +" - would result in 5 and 11 in stack, but no operator to apply.

Comment: Added some information about the input on the question, it will always be valid. Eval is not allowed in any case, except if you language REALLY doesn't have ANY other way to convert strings to number.

Comment: I saw this challenge, was really excited I could use my RProgN's 'do' command and be satisfied. Was disappointed when 'eval not allowed'.

Comment: **XKCD**: [Reverse Polish Sausage](https://xkcd.com/645/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Ruby - <strike>95</strike> 77 characters

```
a=[]
gets.split.each{|b|a<<(b=~/\d/?b.to_f: (j,k=a.pop 2;j.send b,k))}
p a[0]
```

Takes input on stdin.

#### Testing code

```
[
  "-4 5 +",
  "5 2 /",
  "5 2.5 /",
  "5 1 2 + 4 * 3 - +",
  "4 2 5 * + 1 3 2 * + /",
  "12 8 3 * 6 / - 2 + -20.5 "
].each do |test|
  puts "[#{test}] gives #{`echo '#{test}' | ruby golf-polish.rb`}"
end
```

gives

```
[-4 5 +] gives 1.0
[5 2 /] gives 2.5
[5 2.5 /] gives 2.0
[5 1 2 + 4 * 3 - +] gives 14.0
[4 2 5 * + 1 3 2 * + /] gives 2.0
[12 8 3 * 6 / - 2 + -20.5 ] gives 10.0
```

Unlike the C version this returns the last valid result if there are extra numbers appended to the input it seems.

Comment: You could shave off a character by using map instead of each

Answer (score 12):

### Python - 124 chars

```
s=[1,1]
for i in raw_input().split():b,a=map(float,s[:2]);s[:2]=[[a+b],[a-b],[a*b],[a/b],[i,b,a]]["+-*/".find(i)]
print s[0]
```

**Python - 133 chars**

```
s=[1,1]
for i in raw_input().split():b,a=map(float,s[:2]);s={'+':[a+b],'-':[a-b],'*':[a*b],'/':[a/b]}.get(i,[i,b,a])+s[2:]
print s[0]
```

Comment: I like the stack manipulation.

Comment: You can't have `0` as second operand...

Comment: `[a/b]` should be replaced with `b and[a/b]` so that you can have 0 as second operand.

Answer (score 11):

### Scheme, 162 chars

(Line breaks added for clarity—all are optional.)

```
(let l((s'()))(let((t(read)))(cond((number? t)(l`(,t,@s)))((assq t
`((+,+)(-,-)(*,*)(/,/)))=>(lambda(a)(l`(,((cadr a)(cadr s)(car s))
,@(cddr s)))))(else(car s)))))
```

Fully-formatted (ungolfed) version:

```
(let loop ((stack '()))
  (let ((token (read)))
    (cond ((number? token) (loop `(,token ,@stack)))
          ((assq token `((+ ,+) (- ,-) (* ,*) (/ ,/)))
           => (lambda (ass) (loop `(,((cadr ass) (cadr stack) (car stack))
                                    ,@(cddr stack)))))
          (else (car stack)))))
```

---

**Selected commentary**

`` `(,foo ,@bar) `` is the same as `(cons foo bar)` (i.e., it (effectively<sup>†</sup>) returns a new list with `foo` prepended to `bar`), except it's one character shorter if you compress all the spaces out.

Thus, you can read the iteration clauses as `(loop (cons token stack))` and `(loop (cons ((cadr ass) (cadr stack) (car stack)) (cddr stack)))` if that's easier on your eyes.

`` `((+ ,+) (- ,-) (* ,*) (/ ,/)) `` creates an association list with the *symbol* `+` paired with the *procedure* `+`, and likewise with the other operators. Thus it's a simple symbol lookup table (bare words are `(read)` in as symbols, which is why no further processing on `token` is necessary). Association lists have O(n) lookup, and thus are only suitable for short lists, as is the case here. :-P

† This is not technically accurate, but, for non-Lisp programmers, it gets a right-enough idea across.

Comment: Can you read that? Seriously?

Comment: @M28: The ungolfed version, yes. I program in Scheme on a semi-regular basis (for real, serious programs).

Comment: Unfortunately, Scheme is a verbose language and notoriously difficult to golf well. So I wouldn't be surprised to see some Perl submission beat this one.

Comment: I like the four smileys in the golfed version.

Comment: `lambda (ass)` +1 for variable name choice :P

Answer (score 8):

## MATLAB – <strike>158</strike>, 147

```
C=strsplit(input('','s'));D=str2double(C);q=[];for i=1:numel(D),if isnan(D(i)),f=str2func(C{i});q=[f(q(2),q(1)) q(3:end)];else q=[D(i) q];end,end,q
```

(input is read from user input, output printed out).

---

Below is the code prettified and commented, it pretty much implements the [postfix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) described (with the assumption that expressions are valid):

```
C = strsplit(input('','s'));         % prompt user for input and split string by spaces
D = str2double(C);                   % convert to numbers, non-numeric are set to NaN
q = [];                              % initialize stack (array)
for i=1:numel(D)                     % for each value
    if isnan(D(i))                   % if it is an operator
        f = str2func(C{i});          % convert op to a function
        q = [f(q(2),q(1)) q(3:end)]; % pop top two values, apply op and push result
    else
        q = [D(i) q];                % else push value on stack
    end
end
q                                    % show result
```

---

### Bonus:

In the code above, we assume operators are always binary (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). We can generalize it by using `nargin(f)` to determine the number of arguments the operand/function requires, and pop the right amount of values from the stack accordingly, as in:

```
f = str2func(C{i});
n = nargin(f);
args = num2cell(q(n:-1:1));
q = [f(args{:}) q(n+1:end)];
```

That way we can evaluate expressions like:

```
str = '6 5 1 2 mean_of_three 1 + 4 * +'
```

where `mean_of_three` is a user-defined function with three inputs:

```
function d = mean_of_three(a,b,c)
    d = (a+b+c)/3;
end
```

Answer (score 7):

### c -- 424 necessary character

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define O(X) g=o();g=o() X g;u(g);break;
char*p=NULL,*b;size_t a,n=0;float g,s[99];float o(){return s[--n];};
void u(float v){s[n++]=v;};int main(){getdelim(&p,&a,EOF,stdin);for(;;){
b=strsep(&p," \n\t");if(3>p-b){if(*b>='0'&&*b<='9')goto n;switch(*b){case 0:
case EOF:printf("%f\n",o());return 0;case'+':O(+)case'-':O(-)case'*':O(*)
case'/':O(/)}}else n:u(atof(b));}}
```

Assumes that you have a new enough libc to include `getdelim` in stdio.h. The approach is straight ahead, the whole input is read into a buffer, then we tokenize with `strsep` and use length and initial character to determine the class of each. There is no protection against bad input. Feed it "+ - * / + - ...", and it will happily pop stuff off the memory "below" the stack until it seg faults. All non-operators are interpreted as floats by `atof` which means zero value if they don't look like numbers.

**Readable and commented:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *p=NULL,*b;
size_t a,n=0;
float g,s[99];
float o(){        /* pOp */
  //printf("\tpoping '%f'\n",s[n-1]);
  return s[--n];
};
void u(float v){  /* pUsh */
  //printf("\tpushing '%f'\n",v);
  s[n++]=v;
};
int main(){
  getdelim(&p,&a,EOF,stdin); /* get all the input */
  for(;;){
    b=strsep(&p," \n\t"); /* now *b though *(p-1) is a token and p
                 points at the rest of the input */
    if(3>p-b){
      if (*b>='0'&&*b<='9') goto n;
      //printf("Got 1 char token '%c'\n",*b);
      switch (*b) {
      case 0:
      case EOF: printf("%f\n",o()); return 0;
      case '+': g=o(); g=o()+g; u(g); break;
      case '-': g=o(); g=o()-g; u(g); break;
      case '*': g=o(); g=o()*g; u(g); break;
      case '/': g=o(); g=o()/g; u(g); break;
    /* all other cases viciously ignored */
      } 
    } else { n:
      //printf("Got token '%s' (%f)\n",b,atof(b));
      u(atof(b));
    }
  }
}
```

**Validation:**

```
 $ gcc -c99 rpn_golf.c 
 $ wc rpn_golf.c
  9  34 433 rpn_golf.c
 $ echo -4 5 + | ./a.out
1.000000
 $ echo 5 2 / | ./a.out
2.500000
 $ echo 5 2.5 / | ./a.out
2.000000
```

Heh! Gotta quote anything with `*` in it...

```
 $ echo "5 1 2 + 4 * 3 - +" | ./a.out
14.000000
 $ echo "4 2 5 * + 1 3 2 * + /" | ./a.out
2.000000
```

and my own test case

```
 $ echo "12 8 3 * 6 / - 2 + -20.5 " | ./a.out
-20.500000
```

Comment: You can safe some characters by replacing `case` with a makro.

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell (155)

```
f#(a:b:c)=b`f`a:c
(s:_)![]=print s
s!("+":v)=(+)#s!v
s!("-":v)=(-)#s!v
s!("*":v)=(*)#s!v
s!("/":v)=(/)#s!v
s!(n:v)=(read n:s)!v
main=getLine>>=([]!).words
```

Comment: You can get remove 9 characters by changing "(s:_)![]=s" to "(s:_)![]=print s" and "main=getLine>>=putStrLn.show.([]!).words" to "main=getLine>>=([]!).words"

Comment: And then further remove a few other characters by using a one-line case-statement.

Comment: `s!(n:v)=case n of{"+"->(+)#s;"-"->(-)#s;"*"->(*)#s;"/"->(/)#s;_->(read n:s)}!v` would save 14 characters.

Answer (score 6):

### Perl (134)

```
@a=split/\s/,<>;/\d/?push@s,$_:($x=pop@s,$y=pop@s,push@s,('+'eq$_?$x+$y:'-'eq$_?$y-$x:'*'eq$_?$x*$y:'/'eq$_?$y/$x:0))for@a;print pop@s
```

Next time, I'm going to use the recursive regexp thing.

Ungolfed:

```
@a = split /\s/, <>;
for (@a) {
    /\d/
  ? (push @s, $_)
  : ( $x = pop @s,
      $y = pop @s,
      push @s , ( '+' eq $_ ? $x + $y
                : '-' eq $_ ? $y - $x
                : '*' eq $_ ? $x * $y
                : '/' eq $_ ? $y / $x
                : 0 )
      )
}
print(pop @s);
```

I though F# is my only dream programming language...

Comment: I have a shorter Perl 5 implementation.

Answer (score 6):

#### Windows PowerShell, 152 <s>181</s> <s>192</s>

In readable form, because by now it's only two lines with no chance of breaking them up:

```
$s=@()
switch -r(-split$input){
  '\+'        {$s[1]+=$s[0]}
  '-'         {$s[1]-=$s[0]}
  '\*'        {$s[1]*=$s[0]}
  '/'         {$s[1]/=$s[0]}
  '-?[\d.]+'  {$s=0,+$_+$s}
  '.'         {$s=$s[1..($s.count)]}}
$s
```

**2010-01-30 11:07** (192) – First attempt.

**2010-01-30 11:09** (170) – Turning the function into a scriptblock solves the scope issues. Just makes each invocation two bytes longer.

**2010-01-30 11:19** (188) – Didn't solve the scope issue, the test case just masked it. Removed the index from the final output and removed a superfluous line break, though. And changed double to `float`.

**2010-01-30 11:19** (181) – Can't even remember my own advice. Casting to a numeric type can be done in a single char.

**2010-01-30 11:39** (152) – Greatly reduced by using regex matching in the `switch`. Completely solves the previous scope issues with accessing the stack to pop it.

Answer (score 5):

**[Racket](http://racket-lang.org) 131:**

```
(let l((s 0))(define t(read))(cond[(real? t)
(l`(,t,@s))][(memq t'(+ - * /))(l`(,((eval t)(cadr s)
(car s)),@(cddr s)))][0(car s)]))
```

Line breaks optional.

Based on Chris Jester-Young's solution for Scheme.

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 166 characters

```
import os,operator as o
S=[]
for i in os.read(0,99).split():
 try:S=[float(i)]+S
 except:S=[{'+':o.add,'-':o.sub,'/':o.div,'*':o.mul}[i](S[1],S[0])]+S[2:]
print S[0]
```

Comment: Use `raw_input()` code isn't split over multiple lines.

Comment: Then you could try: `from operator import*` and replace `o.div` with `div`.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 119 bytes

```python
s=[]
for x in input().split():
 try:s+=float(x),
 except:o='-*+'.find(x);*s,a,b=s;s+=(a+b*~-o,a*b**o)[o%2],
print(s[0])
```

Input: `5 1 1 - -7 0 * + - 2 /`

Output: `2.5`

(You can find a 128-character Python 2 version in the edit history.)

Comment: Pretty clever :) I like how you don't need `/` in the string.

Comment: [114 bytes](https://tio.run/##DYvBCsMgEAXvfsXeosYkpaUXg18iHrSNVAgquoXm6@3CDHN4vHrhp@THGN1Yx2JpkCBlon6Ri7XXM1E1A2yX7rOJZ/HIk1AMjt/rqKhlV14F03dauZdB@ZlcyC0IO8l5mdaY8ptOTrHaUkbe7c2JMZ5wh@0P)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer that breaks with a `ZeroDivisionError` when the second operand is 0 (e.g. `5 0 +`).

Comment: You can save 1 character by using the `ord(x) - 42` method.

Comment: @frederick99 I don't see how.

Comment: @flornquake `*s,a,b=s;s+=[a*b,a+b,0,a-b,b and a/b][ord(t)-42]`, but i love the current solution better.

Comment: @frederick99 Thank you! In that variant, it would need an extra two characters `0,`, no? `s+=[a*b,a+b,0,a-b,0,b and a/b][ord(x)-42],`

Comment: @flornquake no. have you tried running it?

Comment: @frederick99 Yes ([tio](https://tio.run/##DYvBCsMgEETvfsUek7g2Nm0ppORLxMPaJFQIKq6F5uutzMAbeEw6yyeGW628GCv2mMGDD63pW7r@wunwjbOAks@Z5bIfkUrnexSw/d5bKvPASOgWfjVraHBI0qFGUg4dUFiBRmdNzGt7qftkUaTsQ@nYaNvX@oBriwL1BA0DyDYnGP8) )

Comment: @flornquake mb, none of my test cases had division :l

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (157)

This code assumes there are these two functions: readLine and print

```
a=readLine().split(/ +/g);s=[];for(i in a){v=a[i];if(isNaN(+v)){f=s.pop();p=s.pop();s.push([p+f,p-f,p*f,p/f]['+-*/'.indexOf(v)])}else{s.push(+v)}}print(s[0])
```

Comment: Shorter if you use `prompt()` instead of `readLine()` (and perhaps `alert()` instead of `print()` to match `prompt()`).

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 128

This isn't really competitive next to the other Perl answer, but explores a different (suboptimal) path.

```
perl -plE '@_=split" ";$_=$_[$i],/\d||
do{($a,$b)=splice@_,$i-=2,2;$_[$i--]=
"+"eq$_?$a+$b:"-"eq$_?$a-$b:"*"eq$_?
$a*$b:$a/$b;}while++$i<@_'
```

Characters counted as diff to a simple `perl -e ''` invocation.

Answer (score 3):

## flex - 157

```
%{
float b[100],*s=b;
#define O(o) s--;*(s-1)=*(s-1)o*s;
%}
%%
-?[0-9.]+ *s++=strtof(yytext,0);
\+ O(+)
- O(-)
\* O(*)
\/ O(/)
\n printf("%g\n",*--s);
.
%%
```

If you aren't familiar, compile with `flex rpn.l && gcc -lfl lex.yy.c`

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>439</s> <s>265</s> <s>263</s> <s>262</s> <s>244</s> 240 characters

```
<? $c=fgets(STDIN);$a=array_values(array_filter(explode(" ",$c)));$s[]=0;foreach($a as$b){if(floatval($b)){$s[]=$b;continue;}$d=array_pop($s);$e=array_pop($s);$s[]=$b=="+"?$e+$d:($b=="-"?$e-$d:($b=="*"?$e*$d:($b=="/"?$e/$d:"")));}echo$s[1];
```

This code should work with stdin, though it is not tested with stdin.

It has been tested on all of the cases, the output (and code) for the last one is here:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/fGbnv6

**Ungolfed, <s>314</s> <s>330</s> 326 characters**

```
<?php
$c = fgets(STDIN);
$a = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $c)));
$s[] = 0;
foreach($a as $b){
    if(floatval($b)){
        $s[] = $b;
        continue;
    }
    $d = array_pop($s);
    $e = array_pop($s);
    $s[] = $b == "+" ? $e + $d : ($b == "-" ? $e - $d : ($b == "*" ? $e * $d : ($b == "/" ? $e / $d :"")));
}
echo $s[1];
```

Comment: Quote from the task description: »For programming languages that do not have functions to receive input/output, you can assume functions like readLine/print.« – demonstrably PHP *has* functions to do so, therefore the assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Updated it to use stdin and golfed it a little more.

Answer (score 2):

Python, 161 characters:

```
from operator import*;s=[];i=raw_input().split(' ')
q="*+-/";o=[mul,add,0,sub,0,div]
for c in i:
 if c in q:s=[o[ord(c)-42](*s[1::-1])]+s 
 else:s=[float(c)]+s
print(s[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>126</s> 132 chars

```python
s=[2,2]
for c in input().split():
    a,b=s[:2]
    try:s[:2]=[[a+b,b-a,a*b,a and b/a]["+-*/".index(c)]]
    except:s=[float(c)]+s
print(s[0])
```

There have been better solutions already, but now that I had written it (without having read the prior submissions, of course - even though I have to admit that my code looks as if I had copypasted them together), I wanted to share it, too.

Comment: `b/a` should be replaced with `a and b/a`, otherwise this solution won't work if the second operand is 0 (e.g. `4 0 -`).

Comment: @flornquake Fixed it for him.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 130 characters

Would be 124 characters if we dropped `b and` (which some of the Python answers are missing). And it incorporates 42!

```
s=[]
for x in raw_input().split():
 try:s=[float(x)]+s
 except:b,a=s[:2];s[:2]=[[a*b,a+b,0,a-b,0,b and a/b][ord(x)-42]]
print s[0]
```

Comment: Really nice answer. But I count 130 characters. ;)

Comment: @flornquake you're right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES7, 119 bytes

I'm getting a bug with array comprehensions so I've used `.map`

```
(s,t=[])=>(s.split` `.map(i=>+i?t.unshift(+i):t.unshift((r=t.pop(),o=t.pop(),[r+o,r-o,r*o,r/o]['+-*/'.indexOf(i)]))),t)
```

[Try it online at ESFiddle](http://server.vihan.ml/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3D(s%2Ct%3D%5B%5D)%3D%3E(s.split%60%20%60.map(i%3D%3E%2Bi%3Ft.unshift(%2Bi)%3At.unshift((r%3Dt.pop()%2Co%3Dt.pop()%2C%5Br%2Bo%2Cr-o%2Cr*o%2Cr%2Fo%5D%5B'%2B-*%2F'.indexOf(i)%5D)))%2Ct)%3B%0A%0Af(%2211%203%20%2B%22))

Comment: Is there an ES7 interpreter available?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ this should work on Firefox. You could try http://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: Oh, I see. ^_^ Thanks!

Comment: Fail with input 0

Answer (score 2):

## C 153

Sometimes a program can be made a bit shorter with more golfing and sometimes you just take completely the wrong route and the much better version is found by someone else.

**Thanks to @ceilingcat for finding a much better (and shorter) version**

```
double atof(),s[99],*p=s;y,z;main(c,v)char**v;{for(;--c;*p=z?z-2?~z?z-4?p+=2,atof(*v):*p/y:*p*y:*p-y:*p+y)z=1[*++v]?9:**v-43,y=*p--;printf("%f\n",s[1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7RCoIwGIVfJYRg@7chml3oGHsQ88JWK6F0qA1m1Kv/bd1858A5HI4RN2MQL9Pr/Lju@nWyhPKlreuOg1OLDHyTz34YieGemns/A3j5ttNMpBBGxs6mN1Hqb5JKO6ZK/l8BTxtweYiABJHAAt1U0QJjvtN1E7dEdeBBxVhINw/jakm2t6cxix@KjsoPIlZY4hEBGRZ4iD65/Ac)

My original version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define O(x):--d;s[d]=s[d]x s[d+1];break;
float s[99];main(c,v)char**v;{for(int i=1,d=0;i<c;i++)switch(!v[i][1]?*v[i]:' '){case'+'O(+)case'-'O(-)case'*'O(*)case'/'O(/)default:s[++d]=atof(v[i]);}printf("%f\n",s[1]);}
```

If you are compiling it with mingw32 you need to turn off globbing (see https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-11/msg00052.html) by compiling like this:

```
gcc -std=c99 x.c C:\Applications\mingw32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\CRT_noglob.o
```

If you don't * is automatically expanded by the mingw32 CRT into filenames.

Comment: @ceilingcat  Your version is very different to mine (and a lot more impressive) - it is more like a whole new answer than a gold of mine.  Are you sure you don't want to post it as a completely different answer?

Comment: @ceilingcat  Thanks for all the golfs - I have actually learned a lot of tricks from your updates.

Comment: @ceilingcat Getting rid of the import is really clever.  That would probably save bytes on the other ones too.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <strike>232</strike> 229 bytes

Fun with recursion.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define b *p>47|*(p+1)>47
char*p;float a(float m){float n=strtof(p,&p);b?n=a(n):0;for(;*++p==32;);m=*p%43?*p%45?*p%42?m/n:m*n:m-n:m+n;return*++p&&b?a(m):m;}main(c,v)char**v;{printf("%f\n",a(strtof(v[1],&p)));}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Detect if next char in buffer is a number */
#define b *p > 47 | *(p+1) > 47

char*p; /* the buffer */

float a(float m)
{
    float n = strtof(p, &p); /* parse the next number */

    /* if the next thing is another number, recursively evaluate */
    b ? n = a(n) : 0;

    for(;*++p==32;); /* skip spaces */

    /* Perform the arithmetic operation */
    m = *p%'+' ? *p%'-' ? *p%'*' ? m/n : m*n : m-n : m+n;

    /* If there's more stuff, recursively parse that, otherwise return the current computed value */
    return *++p && b ? a(m) : m;
}

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    printf("%f\n", a(strtof(v[1], &p)));
}
```

### Test Cases:

```
$ ./a.out "-4 5 +"
1.000000
$ ./a.out "5 2 /"
2.500000
$ ./a.out "5 2.5 /"
2.000000
$ ./a.out "5 1 2 + 4 * 3 - +"
14.000000
$ ./a.out "4 2 5 * + 1 3 2 * + /"
2.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP - 259 characters

```
$n=explode(" ",$_POST["i"]);$s=array();for($i=0;$i<count($n);$s=$d-->0?array_merge($s,!$p?array($b,$a,$c):array($p)):$s){if($c=$n[$i++]){$d=1;$a=array_pop($s);$b=array_pop($s);$p=$c=="+"?$b+$a:($c=="-"?$b-$a:($c=="*"?$b*$a:($c=="/"?$b/$a:false)));}}echo$s[2];
```

Assuming input in POST variable *i*.

Comment: Quoted from the original description »For programming languages that do not have functions to receive input/output, you can assume functions like readLine/print.« PHP has a way to get stdin through streams.

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 392 characters

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic{class P{static void Main(){var i=Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');var k=new Stack<float>();float o;foreach(var s in i)switch (s){case "+":k.Push(k.Pop()+k.Pop());break;case "-":o=k.Pop();k.Push(k.Pop()-o);break;case "*":k.Push(k.Pop()*k.Pop());break;case "/":o=k.Pop();k.Push(k.Pop()/o);break;default:k.Push(float.Parse(s));break;}Console.Write(k.Pop());}}}
```

However, if arguments can be used instead of standard input, we can bring it down to

### C# - 366 characters

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic{class P{static void Main(string[] i){var k=new Stack<float>();float o;foreach(var s in i)switch (s){case "+":k.Push(k.Pop()+k.Pop());break;case "-":o=k.Pop();k.Push(k.Pop()-o);break;case "*":k.Push(k.Pop()*k.Pop());break;case "/":o=k.Pop();k.Push(k.Pop()/o);break;default:k.Push(float.Parse(s));break;}Console.Write(k.Pop());}}}
```

Comment: You can save 23 characters with a little optimization: 1. remove the namespace trick, explicitly qualify the two types that need it. You save the "namespace" keyword and corresponding brackets. 2. Remove spaces between string[] and i, case keywords and labels, switch and its parens. 3. Get rid of float o and simply use math to get the right results (ie. -k.Pop()+k.Pop() for minus, and 1/k.Pop()*k.Pop() for divide.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala <strike>412 376 349 335</strike> 312:

```
object P extends App{
def p(t:List[String],u:List[Double]):Double={
def a=u drop 2
t match{
case Nil=>u.head
case x::y=>x match{
case"+"=>p(y,u(1)+u(0)::a)
case"-"=>p(y,u(1)-u(0)::a)
case"*"=>p(y,u(1)*u(0)::a)
case"/"=>p(y,u(1)/u(0)::a)
case d=>p(y,d.toDouble::u)}}}
println(p((readLine()split " ").toList,Nil))}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# - <strike>323</strike> <strike>284</strike> 241

```cs
class P{static void Main(string[] i){int x=0;var a=new float[i.Length];foreach(var s in i){var o="+-*/".IndexOf(s);if(o>-1){float y=a[--x],z=a[--x];a[x++]=o>3?z/y:o>2?z*y:o>1?z-y:y+z;}else a[x++]=float.Parse(s);}System.Console.Write(a[0]);}}
```

Edit: Replacing the Stack with an Array is way shorter

Edit2: Replaced the ifs with a ternary expression

Comment: `string[] i`=>`string[]i`.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 159

```
sub c{pop@s}sub z{push@s,$_[0]}while(<>){($_,$a)=/(\S*) ?(.*)/;z$_ if/\d/;z(('-'eq$_?- c:c)+c)if/[+-]/;z(('/'eq$_?1/c:c)*c)if/[*\/]/;redo if$_=$a;print c."\n"}
```

And here's the ungolfed version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
 
sub c{pop @stack}
sub z{push @stack,$_[0]}
while (<>) {
    ($_, $a) = /(\S*) ?(.*)/;
    z$_ if /\d/;
    z(('-'eq$_?- c:c)+c) if /[+-]/;
    z(('/'eq$_?1/c:c)*c) if /[*\/]/;
    redo if $_=$a;
    print c . "\n"
}
```

Not really much to look at, but I'm pretty happy with it.  I managed to at least beat the Scheme version :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2

I've tried out some different approaches to the ones published so far.  None of these is quite as short as the best Python solutions, but they might still be interesting to some of you.

### Using recursion, 146

```python
def f(s):
 try:x=s.pop();r=float(x)
 except:b,s=f(s);a,s=f(s);r=[a+b,a-b,a*b,b and a/b]['+-*'.find(x)]
 return r,s
print f(raw_input().split())[0]
```

### Using list manipulation, 149

```python
s=raw_input().split()
i=0
while s[1:]:
 o='+-*/'.find(s[i])
 if~o:i-=2;a,b=map(float,s[i:i+2]);s[i:i+3]=[[a+b,a-b,a*b,b and a/b][o]]
 i+=1
print s[0]
```

### Using `reduce()`, 145

```python
print reduce(lambda s,x:x in'+-*/'and[(lambda b,a:[a+b,a-b,a*b,b and a/b])(*s[:2])['+-*'.find(x)]]+s[2:]or[float(x)]+s,raw_input().split(),[])[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 206

```
import sys;i=sys.argv[1].split();s=[];a=s.append;b=s.pop
for t in i:
 if t=="+":a(b()+b())
 elif t=="-":m=b();a(b()-m)
 elif t=="*":a(b()*b())
 elif t=="/":m=b();a(b()/m)
 else:a(float(t))
print(b())
```

Ungolfed version:

```
# RPN

import sys

input = sys.argv[1].split()
stack = []

# Eval postfix notation
for tkn in input:
    if tkn == "+":
        stack.append(stack.pop() + stack.pop())
    elif tkn == "-":
        tmp = stack.pop()
        stack.append(stack.pop() - tmp)
    elif tkn == "*":
        stack.append(stack.pop() * stack.pop())
    elif tkn == "/":
        tmp = stack.pop()
        stack.append(stack.pop()/tmp)
    else:
        stack.append(float(tkn))

print(stack.pop())
```

Input from command-line argument; output on standard output.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript 6 (131)

Just typed together in a few seconds, so it can probably be golfed further or maybe even approached better. I might revisit it tomorrow:

```
f=s=>(p=[],s.split(/\s+/).forEach(t=>+t==t?p.push(t):(b=+p.pop(),a=+p.pop(),p.push(t=='+'?a+b:t=='-'?a-b:t=='*'?a*b:a/b))),p.pop())
```

Answer (score 1):

### Matlab, 228

```
F='+-/*';f={@plus,@minus,@rdivide,@times};t=strsplit(input('','s'),' ');i=str2double(t);j=~isnan(i);t(j)=num2cell(i(j));while numel(t)>1
n=find(cellfun(@(x)isstr(x),t),1);t{n}=bsxfun(f{t{n}==F},t{n-2:n-1});t(n-2:n-1)=[];end
t{1}
```

Ungolfed:

```
F = '+-/*'; %// possible operators
f = {@plus,@minus,@rdivide,@times}; %// to be used with bsxfun
t = strsplit(input('','s'),' '); %// input string and split by one or multiple spaces
i = str2double(t); %// convert each split string to number
j =~ isnan(i); %// these were operators, not numbers ...
t(j) = num2cell(i(j)); %// ... so restore them
while numel(t)>1
    n = find(cellfun(@(x)isstr(x),t),1); %// find left-most operator
    t{n} = bsxfun(f{t{n}==F}, t{n-2:n-1}); %// apply it to preceding numbers and replace
    t(n-2:n-1)=[]; %// remove used numbers
end
t{1} %// display result
```

Comment: You can save 2 more bytes by putting everything onto one line (or use a text editor which only uses one character for newline)

Comment: @Hoki I'm only using new lines when not breaking the line would require a `;`. So I think the byte count is the same

Comment: not exactly, most window text editors use `cr+lf` for a newline, which is 2 characters. My notepad++ counted 230 characters in your 3 lines version, but only 128 if I stick everything in one line (removed 2*2=4 characters from the 2 newlines, and added two `;`). Try it yourself ;)

Comment: @Hoki You are right. In fact, if I paste the three-line version on https://mothereff.in/byte-counter (which is what I used for counting text bytes), it gives 228. And of course that's also what I get from putting it all in a single line. I don't know where I got the number 230 from. Thanks! Corrected

Answer (score 1):

## K5, 70 bytes

```
`0:*{$[-9=@*x;((*(+;-;*;%)@"+-*/"?y).-2#x;x,.y)@47<y;(.x;.y)]}/" "\0:`
```

I'm not sure when K5 was released, so this *might* not count. Still awesome!

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 265 bytes

Worse than first thought, looking for improvements.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stack>
#define G s.top();s.pop()
using namespace std;int main(){string t; stack<float>s;while(cin>>t)if(47<t.back()&t.back()<58)s.push(stof(t));else{float a,b=G;a=G;s.push(t=="+"?a+b:t=="-"?a-b:t=="*"?a*b:a/b);}cout<<G;}
```

**Usage**

```
Run -> input -> enter -> Ctrl+Z -> enter  (windows)
                      -> Ctrl+D           (unix)
```

Ungolfed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#define G s.top(); s.pop()
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string t;
    stack<float> s;
    while (cin >> t)
    {
        if (47 < t.back() & t.back() < 58)
            s.push(stof(t));
        else
        {
            float a, b = G;
            a = G;
            s.push(t=="+" ? a+b : t=="-" ? a-b : t=="*" ? a*b : a/b);
        }
    }
    cout << G;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Mathetmatica, 143 bytes

```
Last@Flatten[#~ImportString~"CSV"&/@StringSplit@#]//.{{a___,b_,c_,o_String,d___}:>{a,o[b,c],d},"+"->Plus,"*"->Times,"/"->Divide,"-"->Subtract}&
```

Anonymous function, takes a string as input (`StringSplit[#]`), splits at whitespace, `ImportString[#,"CSV"]` acts on each element separately (it's like a soft form of eval), converting number-like strings to numbers, however operators remain as strings.

`//.` - repeatedly apply replacement rule: go through the input list, until you hit an operator character, e.g. `{1, 4, 2, / *}` becomes `{1 /[4,2] *}`, then `{*[1, /[4,2]]}`.

String-forms of operators are replaced with the names of the actual Mathematica functions which do the required thing. Output is a number.

Comment: I'm disappointed Mathematica doesn't have a builtin ...

Comment: `Last` must be applied to the whole expression, not just the input: `Last[Flatten[#~ImportString~"CSV" & /@ StringSplit@#] //. {{a___, b_, c_, o_String, d___} :> {a, o[b, c], d}, "+" -> Plus, "*" -> Times, "/" -> Divide, "-" -> Subtract}] &`. [142 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYxRi4JAFIX/yuUOyJZ3Grb0sRCKhYUeBKMXkWFS2R3QjLrbi@hfd69Eb9/5Due0jn/r1rEv3ZTCdjq6B@dfjWOur7kav9tbd@eM7/76M@I@O2NgklfMbo3nRBXGrPreWWvpYqm01NlXT5W4Qe96R5exG0uqBsIQ9S5t/h6EWuhDabUOFoRLCSff1uKN4ME/fVUPRTCl8sS5klGuiiIAk0CPMazBIMEMq/iNn2JDiGAJG9AQzjISFYsIpdwIz2RwmP4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#vyDd≠i©'+Qi+ë®'-Qi-ë®'*Qi*ë/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fuazSJeVR54LMQyvVtQMztQ@vPrROXTcwUxfM0ArM1Dq8Wv//fxMFIwVTBS0FbQVDBWMgG8TSBwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVqmupHd4h72SwqO2SQpK9pX/lcsqXVIedS7IPLRSXTswU/vw6kPr1HUDM3XBDK3ATK3Dq/X/14KAzn9dEwVTBW0uUwUjBX0QqWcKpg2BfG0FEwUtBWMFXaC8CZBvCuRpA2WMgWwQSx8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
#                # Split the (implicit) input-string on spaces
 vy              # Loop `y` over each item:
   D             #  Duplicate `y` so it's now twice on the stack
    d≠i          #  If it's NOT a number:
       ©         #   Store the operator-character in variable `®` (without popping)
        '+Qi    '#   If it's a "+":
            +    #    Add the top two numbers together
       ë®'-Qi   '#   Else-if it's a "-":
             -   #    Subtract the top two numbers from each other
       ë®'*Qi   '#   Else-if it's a "*":
             *   #    Multiply the top two numbers together
       ë         #   Else (it's a "/"):
        /        #    Divide the top two numbers
                 # (after the loop: implicitly output the result)
```

We're using the legacy version, because `d` checks if a value is a number, whereas the new 05AB1E version would check if it's a non-negative number (\$\geq0\$) instead.

---

If `eval` would have been allowed, it's **<s>14</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead:

```
9LD(s'(«:.V
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0sdFo1hd49BqK72w//9NFIwUTBW0FLQVDBWMgWwQSx8A) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVqmupHd4h72SwqO2SQpK9pX/LX1cNIrVNQ6tttIL@6/zX9dEwVRBm8tUwUhBH0TqmYJpQyBfW8FEQUvBWEEXKG8C5JsCedpAGWMgG8TSBwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
9L           # Push the list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  D          # Duplicate it on the stack
   (         # Negate each integer: [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9]
    s        # Swap to get the original list again
     '(«    '# Append a "(" to each: ["1(","2(","3(","4(","5(","6(","7(","8(","9("]
        :    # Replace all "-N" with "N(" in the (implicit) input-string
         .V  # Eval the string as 05AB1E code
             # (implicitly output the result)
```

Negative numbers are indicated with a trailing `(` instead of leading `-` in 05AB1E. Apart from that, the calculations are also done in Reverse Polish Notation style.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>132 105</s> 96 bytes

```r
for(i in scan(,""))F="if"(grepl("[0-9]",i),c(as.double(i),F),c(get(i)(F[2],F[1]),F[-1:-2]));F[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchBCoAgEEDRq8isZkijpBYVbb2EuCizEMTC6vxmu/9fynk/E3rmI7vtEpEDEKkZ/A54JHcFBN2IwQD3xC0ud72d7xocllW/HO4pjUpLw5VuTWEt2lFIQzT9kEXHelblDw)

[Port of Amro's Matlab answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54016/80010) I never realized the two languages had so much in common.
Saved 27 bytes thanks to Giuseppe ! See edit history for test cases.

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYvNDoIwEITP@BSbetmFFkKBxKi8hTfCwR9KmhAwgInV@Oy4FW8z3zczLgaOajGP/jrboceXfJZNh9M8TvfOztwFCCLpyveH3mYY0YLt4UmuFNYIbMfm3qGVIgpVIqQpTySv2DYzWkJX6Vq6Kq35X6l0r3Tt7XmKb8Pj0jW8kY7o4D6LQaFyKCASFATBFtINkx1kHsBKfqiAFDREkEPIUv0129zbnF3BJuJVxtmnxC@2oNe3jouV@JNevg)

Comment: using `scan(,"")` to split the input string (and changing to a full program) is probably a good golf; it would take input as `1 3 +` instead of `"1 3 +"`

Comment: @Giuseppe it is a good golf indeed!

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 118 bytes

```
?!/rRlril1-{=
R:0q}"+0"{:}≠?\"-0"{:}≠?\"*0"{:}≠?\"/0"{≠?\R}l1=?!@
\r\ /<?6+{{~{~/?7-S{{~{~/?8 *{{~{~/?7,S{{~/\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99eUb8oKKcoM8dQt9qWK8jKoLBWSdtAqdqq1vbMDvsYJV0kthYSWx/IBrOCanMMbe0VHbhiimIU9G3szbSrq@uq6/TtzXWDoSwLBS2YmA5ITD/m/38TBSMFUwUtBW0FQwVjIBvE0gcA)

Runic already operates in Reverse Polish Notation, so its just a matter of reading the input and converting from char-based symbols to actual operators.

Due to the near-perfect space usage on the lower line, `≠?\` works out to the same number of bytes as `=?!\`, but is easier to read.

#### Explanation

```
    /<                                                Entry
?!\rRlril1-{=                                         Read all inputs
/r/                                                   Reverse the stack (we need to parse from front to back, not back to front; mirrors flipped to preserve visual flow direction within the explanation)
R                                                     Initial parsing loop entry
 :                                                    Duplicate
  0q}                                                 Concat TOS with a 0 on the end
     "+0"                                             Construct string +0 (checking for addition)
         {:}                                          RoL, Dup, RoR (this allows the same i0 string concatenation to be reused)
            ≠?\                                       Compare, if not equal, continue
               "-0"{:}≠?\"*0"{:}≠?\"/0"{≠?\           Do the same for -, *, and /
                                           R          Bottom-of-loop entry
                                            }         Rotate numerical value to bottom of stack
                                             l1=?!@   If stack is only 1 object, print and terminate
           ~{~/                                       If equal, pop no-longer-needed i0 concatenations and the original input char
        +{{                                           Add most recent 2 values
      ?6                                              Skip to bottom-of-loop
               ?7-S{{~{~/?8 *{{~{~/?7,S{{~/           Similar chunks for -, *, and /
                                           \          Mirror up to bottom of main loop (after-math skips wind up here)
                                     ,S{{~            Note that division does not need to pop no-longer-needed concatenated string, as we used up the last one in the comparison
```

Invalid input characters will be [treated as their decimal equivalents](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99eUb8oKKcoM8dQt9qWK8jKoLBWSdtAqdqq1vbMDvsYJV0kthYSWx/IBrOCanMMQQwHrpiiGAV9G3sz7erquuo6fXtz3WAoy0JBCyamAxLTj/n/31HBUEEbAA) because `char`s implicitly convert to `int`s. Strings [will crash](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/99eUb8oKKcoM8dQt9qWK8jKoLBWSdtAqdqq1vbMDvsYJV0kthYSWx/IBrOCanMMQQwHrpiiGAV9G3sz7erquuo6fXtz3WAoy0JBCyamAxLTj/n/39HJWcFQQRsA).

Operators *must* be compared with their string equivalents, again, because `char`s implicitly convert to `int`s. A [numerical `43` is identical to the character `+`](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/19dO9PW4f9/E2MA). `0q` is the shortest method of generating a unique string representation of the stack object that can be compared with known expected strings. Additionally a string *may not be the ToS* when constructing a new string or the two strings are [automatically concatenated](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9TycXVTUnF@v9/RydnAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 92 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=(d,c=q.pop())=>1/c?+c:(b=g(d=g()),c)>'-'?b/d:c>'+'?b-d:c>'*'?b+d:b*d)(q=s.split(/ +/))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hco9DoQgEEDhq0zHDAjE/WlMBjvvoYMxboygmL2@S7Z4yVe8z/gdi5xrvuye4nwPwHAXDrgwxkb4cDllJOLQeumNdDjxgrFG1AgFZVU/@dhJUKbK/qWrTOwmHQkPLq7kbb3Qg/FEt6S9pG12W1pwQPWGFuABBl6gwT7BglH1@gE)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2.7 (205 bytes)

Edit: Version 2. After consideration I was able to shave off a lot by using the operator module:

```python
from operator import *
f={'*':mul,'/':div,'+':add,'-':sub}
def e(r):
    l=[]
    for i in r:
        try:i=float(i);l.append(i)
        except:l.append(f[i](*l[-2:]));del l[-3:-1]
    return l
print e(raw_input().split())[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 243

Input comes from the command line. Element 0 in the Float[ ] isn't actually used for storing the inputs, however it is needed for the first assignment of the temp value. The Float constructor takes care of parsing for negative values and values with a decimal place.

```
interface R{static void main(String[]a){Float t,f[]=new Float[a.length];int i=0;for(String s:a){t=f[i];switch(s){case"-":t=-t;case"+":f[--i]+=t;break;case"/":t=1/t;case"*":f[--i]*=t;break;default:f[++i]=new Float(s);}}System.out.print(f[i]);}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
interface ReversePolishNotation{
    static void main(String[]arg){
        Float temp, fVals[]=new Float[arg.length];
        int i=0;
        for(String str:arg){
            temp=fVals[i];
            switch(str){
                case"-":
                    temp=-temp;
                case"+":
                    fVals[--i]+=temp; break;
                case"/":
                    temp=1/temp;
                case"*":
                    fVals[--i]*=temp; break;
                default:
                    fVals[++i]=new Float(str);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(fVals[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @RikerW how do you mean? If it's a style issue, I don't see the harm in leaving it the way it is.

Comment: Oh NVM. :P I was thinking about the *un*golfed version. Oops, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 175 bytes

```
{var s=List(0){0f}
for(t in it.split(" ")){try{s=s+t.toFloat()}catch(e:Exception){val(a,b)=s.takeLast(2)
s=s.dropLast(2)+listOf(a+b,a-b,a*b,a/b)["+-*/".indexOf(t)]}}
s.last()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY8xT8QwDIX3/gqrk3295k4nppMKE0yVGBgRg9umEF1IqsScDlX57cUgLL3Bevqe/S5RvAvblT2kJZwBXyS58E7Q3sOTjyzQbeuVE@Sud1nwSOtxLtUcEwq4AE5MXrwTrKEmWiV9r7nLjRiJfzhSGVnGD7Tnx9toF3ExkAZ65P1AXTbCF9uzJp@oUtJMKS7/e@P14vOM3Ax7blU71WGg17ppd4fauDDZm/pCb6VU2fhfjMo2fwX4ZBeQYK1AZ9FKgtoPk@Wpd8Gq9XCGWl@uytbewQmaHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 196 bytes

```
F(l,n)=>l.removeAt(l.length-1-n);G(a,b,c)=>c=='+'?a+b:c=='-'?a-b:c=='*'?a*b:a/b;f(s){var l=[];s.split(' ').forEach((a){l.add('+-*/'.contains(a)?G(F(l,1),F(l,0),a):double.parse(a));});return l[0];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDLboMwEEX3@YpZRLINthMS2GCRqIs2H4FYmEcekmOQMdkgvp0OtGqzsY/uvTOeca2dn@cvarhl2clI1zzbV/PhqZGmsTd/F5GwTF2o5iWvMFJlGQnJWYdluqBAFD8YIAZlqnelutKejS/twGR5oXrZd@bhKQHC5LV1n7q6U6rZaKSua0pCEeyIrFrr9cP2aJwvdJkoYny59oxrltbtUJpGdtr1DUaYmphyjR@cBZPvCzXNT6ymbNwALC/7LEcCyImIIYGQ8Kjgv0oCB9gRfpDJuySTVXyTIsyFEEMARxBri/jPjdFL0AkxdUReaC1Hv1AbPP3/rsM6FkDnHhb/YTte6YBDswmyE2zHIY@KiTCFGdxqM83f)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5.10+: 95 bytes

```
perl '-anEmy@a;push@a,/\d/?$_:do{$j=pop@a;$i=pop@a;($i*$j,$i+$j,0,$i-$j,0,$i/$j)[-42+ord]}for@F;say$a[0]'
```

Size 95 bytes (diff with `perl -e ''` which is 10 bytes).

Ungolfed, expanding command line flags (thanks to `perl -MO=Deparse '-anE...`) and slightly edited:

```
use feature 'say';
while (defined($_ = readline)) {
    our @F = split(' ', $_, 0);
    my @a;
    push @a, /\d/ ? $_ : do {
        $j = pop @a;
        $i = pop @a;
        ($i * $j, $i + $j, 0, $i - $j, 0, $i / $j)[-42 + ord($_)]
    } foreach (@F);
    say $a[0];
}
```

Notes:

- See documentation of [perl command line
  switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) about `-a`, `-n` and `-E`
- ASCII values of the following chars are useful to understand the
  expression involving `ord`:

  > ```
  > * 42
  > + 43
  > - 45
  > / 47
  > ```

### An alternate implementation using regexp matching and replacement: 100 bytes

```
perl '-pEwhile(s!\b([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s+([-+*/])!" ".($1*$2,$1+$2,0,$1-$2,0,$1/$2)[-42+ord$3]!e){}y/ //d'
```

Ungolfed:

```
use feature 'say';

while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    while (s[\b([-0-9.]+)\s+([-0-9.]+)\s+([-+*/])][' ' . ($1 * $2, $1 + $2, 0, $1 - $2, 0, $1 / $2)[-42 + ord($3)];]e) {
        ();
    }
    y/ //d;
} continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Comment: You can just say perl 5

Comment: @ASCII-only `say` and `-E` appeared only with Perl v5.10. Sorry if I'm an old-schooler and pedant.

Comment: hmm. "-a implicitly sets -n". also... what do you need -E for then

Answer (score 0):

### **Javascript, 112 bytes**

```
r=c=>(s=[],f=(a,b,o)=>eval(`${b}${o}${a}`),c.split(' ').forEach(e=>s.push(!+e?f(s.pop(),s.pop(),e):+e)),s.pop())
```

Zero error checking, uses the eval function, but it works with all valid RPN expressions.

r is a function (eg. r('2 3 +') returns 4)

Comment: Quote from the OP: _You are not allowed to use any kind of "eval" in the program._

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 172 bytes  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N81qc))

```
<?foreach(preg_split('~ +~',fgets(STDIN))as$v)if(floatval($v))$s[]=$v;else{[$e,$d]=array_splice($s,-2);$s[]=$v=="+"?$e+$d:($v=="-"?$e-$d:($v=="*"?$e*$d:$e/$d));}echo $s[0];
```

Previously entertained techniques:

```
<?do{$_GET[a]=preg_replace_callback('~(-?[\d.]+) +(-?[\d.]+) +([*/+-])~',fn($m)=>($m[3]=='+'?$m[1]+$m[2]:($m[3]=='-'?$m[1]-$m[2]:($m[3]=='*'?$m[1]*$m[2]:$m[1]/$m[2]))),$_GET[a],1,$c);}while($c);echo $_GET[a]; // 208

<?$v=$_GET[a];do{$v=preg_replace_callback('~(-?[\d.]+) +(-?[\d.]+) +([*/+-])~',fn($m)=>($m[3]=='+'?$m[1]+$m[2]:($m[3]=='-'?$m[1]-$m[2]:($m[3]=='*'?$m[1]*$m[2]:$m[1]/$m[2]))),$v,1,$c);}while($c);echo $v; // 202

<?while(preg_match('~(.*?)(-?[\d.]+) (-?[\d.]+) ([*/+-])(.*)~',$_GET[a],$m))$_GET[a]=$m[1].($m[4]=='+'?$m[2]+$m[3]:($m[4]=='-'?$m[2]-$m[3]:($m[4]=='*'?$m[2]*$m[3]:$m[2]/$m[3]))).$m[5];echo $_GET[a]; // 198

<?$v=$_GET[a];while(preg_match('~(.*?)(-?[\d.]+) +(-?[\d.]+) +([*/+-])(.*)~',$v,$m))$v=$m[1].($m[4]=='+'?$m[2]+$m[3]:($m[4]=='-'?$m[2]-$m[3]:($m[4]=='*'?$m[2]*$m[3]:$m[2]/$m[3]))).$m[5];echo $v;  // 194
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 106

```
e=i=>i.split(' ').reduce((s,t)=>[s,isNaN(t)?eval([s.pop(),s.pop()].reverse().join(t+' ')):t].flat(),[])[0]
```

**Testing code**

```
console.log([
    '-4 5 +',
    '5 2 /',
    '5 2.5 /',
    '5 1 2 + 4 * 3 - +',
    '4 2 5 * + 1 3 2 * + /'
].map(e))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2.5, 2, 14, 2]
```

UPD I've just noticed that eval is not allowed, but it's not the only JS solution with eval so I'd let it posted

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 104 bytes

```
{for(;i++<NF;d[e]=b?--b?--b?--b?f/g:f*g:f-g:f+g:$i)(b=index("+-*/",$i))?(g=d[e--])(f=d[e]):e++}1,$0=d[e]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SMM6U1vbxs/NOiU6NdY2yV5XF4HT9NOt0rSAWBeItdOtVDI1NZJsM/NSUis0lLR1tfSVdIBCmvYa6bZA3bq6sZoaaSBWrKZVqrZ2raGOigGY@/@/qYKhgpGCtoKJgpaCsYKugjYA)

This one mostly abuses ternaries like a case statement to save characters... The code loops through each conditional argument, setting variable `b` to 0-5 depending on whether the argument is a number (`b==0`) or an index 1-4 into the string `"+-*/"`.  Then the "end of loop" code uses `b` to either compute the results of a mathematical operation, or just to reference the current argument.

It uses array `d` like a stack.

```
for(;i++<NF;                                     ) - loops through args
            d[e]=b?--b?--b?--b?f/g:f*g:f-g:f+g:$i  - effectively a "case" statement
```

And the body of the loop does:

```
(b=index("+-*/",$i))?                  :    - sets "b" to 0-5, also if/then/else
                     (g=d[e--])(f=d[e])     - set "f" and "g" to args to be used in math
                                        e++ - for numbers, advance stack pointer
```

And once all the argument have been processed:

```
1,$0=d[e] - the "1," forces output even if "d[e]" is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 112 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split` `.map(i=>1/i?i&&t.push(+i):t.push([(r=t.pop())+(o=t.pop()),o-r,r*o,o/r]['+-*/'.indexOf(i)]),t=[])&&t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc5LDoIwEIDhq8wKOvRB8LHRFI/gAQgJhIeOQaZpq/H2lYVx963@/I/@3YfBk4t65XFKMzNYSMHWwQS3UOygM8/eCbJ1VdKFsiwa9wp3IQlPPzbC243sBKIU/Ldi7ZUvWHHp2yaXuihzQ@s4fa6zIGxRRdu0uCXTGQZeAy@TWfgmtguRH6EC2IGEAxSwBw0yR0xf)

Modified from an existing answer but did thorough modify :(

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 87 bytes

```factor
[ " "split [ dup dec> [ dec> ] [ last "+-*/"index { + - * / } nth execute ] if ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY89C8JADIZ3f8XLjZa2qO2i4CouLuIkHY5r1MN6nncpKOJvr2kFNUPy5OMNyUEbvoZut11vVnNE31hm6444U3DU4KL5NLjM6xApINKtJWcowgdifvhgHWMxeo4gptICJRL1SUpMkf84K/@yifQSFBhjhvSrKKRaSi2R/ky4J9G8uj0U1HAd9qhbj5rMssc@VAKNjgyVpONcWVfTHU@RprIgxwtOnqA7mZZJhu1BHGlzQtVdtEfWvQE)

Or, if word lookup (i.e. converting a string to an executable function of the same name) doesn't count as too eval-y:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 72 bytes

```factor
[ " "split [ dup dec> [ dec> ] [ "math"lookup-word execute ] if ] each ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xC8IwEIV3f8Ujo6UVbbsouIqLizhJh5BebWlNY5KiIv72elFQb3j33XscvEoq39vxsN/uNks40zXeN/qElqymDmfp67ckRlpHFo4uA2lFDsaS93djG@1x7W3psJo8JuARcYYckfgcORaY/TjJ/645ZxEyTJEi/n5k7ObsRZynzIH45zkeISDeHXFEORiUpNYBwyoYRKgqur5vBxOHUqAbqcETp03FQlLVKMazNEjGFw)