# Basic Calculator

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

You must write a program to evaluate a string that would be entered into a calculator.

The program must accept input and output the correct answer.  For languages that do not have standard input/output functions, you may assume the functions `readLine` and `print`.

**Requirements**

- Does not use any kind of "eval" functions
- Can handle floating point and negative numbers
- Supports at least the +, -, *, and / operators
- Can handle input containing one **or more** spaces between the operators and numbers
- Evaluates the expression from left to right

The program that is the shortest wins.  In the event of a tie, the program that was submitted first wins.

**You can assume that the input is valid and follows the correct format**

### Test Cases

Input

```
-4 + 5
```

Output

```
1
```

---

Input

```
-7.5 / 2.5
```

Output

```
-3
```

---

Input

```
-2 + 6 / 2 * 8 - 1 / 2.5 - 18
```

Output

```
-12
```

Comment: [My calculator](http://www.hpmuseum.org/hp11c.htm) uses [postfix](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221/reverse-polish-notation). See also [Evaluating Mathematical Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928563/) on Stack Overflow for competition (though I haven't checked if the rules are identical).

Comment: Third test case is wrong - whether you follow standard order of operations or perform all operations left to right. Looking at the second test case, does your calculator round the result of each operation?

Comment: Fixed the second and third test case, the result is not rounded.

Comment: The third test case does not follow the standard order of operations.  Are our answers supposed to?

Comment: @John, the last requirement says it needs to evaluate the string from left to right.  This means it doesn't follow the standard order of operations.

Comment: @Bass: Ok, just clarifying.

Comment: What about using command line arguments ARGV? because the shell auto-splits and lists the arguments.

Comment: This is really trivial if you're just calculating left to right, and not using standard operator precedence. I was hoping to get a chance to show off my knowledge of Dijkstra's Shunting Yard algorithm here but I guess that won't be necessary.

Comment: An advanced calculator challenge would be fun

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs already exists http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/617/148

Comment: @KevinBrown Cool! I didn't see that.

Comment: How much floating-point precision does it have to support?

Comment: May we use fixed-point or rational numbers instead of floating-point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Ruby - <s>74</s> <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 65 characters

```
a=0
("+ "+$<.read).split.each_slice 2{|b,c|a=a.send b,c.to_f}
p a
```

Comment: Instead of using `b[0],b[1].to_f` you can replace `|b|` with `|b,c|` and use `b,c.to_f`

Comment: Instead of `a.send(b,c.to_f)`, use `a.send b,c.to_f`. It saves a char

Comment: You can use `$<` instead of `ARGF`

Answer (score 9):

### Befunge - <strike>37 x 5 = 185</strike> 38 x 3 = 114 characters

This is limited to integer numbers as Befunge has no floating point support.

```
&v      /& _ #`&# "-"$# -#<          v
 >~:0`!#v_:" "`! #v_:","`#^_"*"`#v_&*>
 ^      ># $ .# @#<              >&+
```

#### Explanation

The biggest distinguishing feature of [Befunge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) is that instead of being a linear set of instructions like most languages; it is a 2d grid of single character instructions, where control can flow in any direction.

The first `&` simply inputs the first number.  The `v` and `>` then redirect control to the main path on the second row.

```
~:0`!#v_
```

This inputs a character (`~`), duplicates it (`:`), pushes zero onto the stack (`0`), pops the top two elements and determines if the second is greater than the first (`` ` `` *I'm surprised you can't use ``` to get code backticks.*), inverts the truthiness of the top element (`!`), then goes right if it is zero, down otherwise (`#v_`).

Basically it's checking whether the input is `-1` representing no more input.

```
># $ .# @
```

If the input was `-1` then the duplicated input value is discarded (`$`), the top of the stack is output as an integer (`.`) and the program is halted (`@`).

```
:" "`! #v_
```

Otherwise a similar process is repeated to determine if the input is less than or equal to a space.  If it is a space then control goes down, otherwise control heads right.

```
^      ># $ .# @#<
```

If it is a space then it's redirected left (`<`); the program halt (`@`), output (`.`) and right redirection (`>`) are all skipped using `#`; but the discard is executed to remove the space from the stack.  Finally it's redirected up to begin the next execution (`^`).

```
:","`#^_
```

If it wasn't a space the same process is used to split on if it is in `[+, *]` or in `[-, \]` going right and up respectively.

```
 >~                         "*"`#v_&*>
 ^                               >&+
```

For `[+, *]` it is again split to determine whether it is a `+` or a `*`.  If `+` it is directed down then the next number is input (`&`) and they are added (`+`), the control then wraps around and is redirected up to the main path for the next character.  If `*` then it inputs (`&`) and multiplies (`*`) then directly wraps around.

```
/& _ #`&# "-"$# -#<
```

For `[-, \]` it starts on the right heading left.  The `#`'s skip the character after them so the initial path is `` "-"`_ `` which simply determines if it is `-` or `/`.  If it is `/` then it continues left to input (`&`) and divide (`/`).  If it is `-` then it heads right, again skipping characters so that it executes `&"-"$-` resulting in the number being input (`&`) the `-` character being pushed onto the stack then discarded (`"-"$`) and then the subtraction being calculated (`-`).  The control is then redirected back to the main path.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 105 bytes

Manages the four basic operations, but it only costs 5 characters each to add `^` or `%`.

```python
f=float
x,*l=input().split()
while l:o,y,*l=l;x,y=f(x),f(y);x=[x+y,x-y,x*y,x/y]['+-*/'.find(o)]
print(x)
```

Precedence of operations is left to right.

Answer (score 5):

### Python (156)

```
from operator import*
while 1:
 l=raw_input().split();f=float
 while len(l)>2:l[:3]=({'*':mul,'/':div,'+':add,'-':sub}[l[1]](f(l[0]),f(l[2])),)
 print l[0]
```

Comment: It's prob just easier to use Python 3

Answer (score 5):

## C - <s>168</s> 126 characters

```
main(c){float a,b;scanf("%f",&a);while(scanf("%s%f",&c,&b)!=-1)c=='+'?a+=b:c=='-'?(a-=b):c=='*'?(a*=b):(a/=b);printf("%f",a);}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Tcl 8.6, <s>57</s> 48 chars.

- Input from arguments:

  ```
  lm o\ b [las $argv a] {set a [exp $a$o$b]};pu $a
  ```
- From Stdin (<s>64</s> **53**)

  ```
  lm o\ b [las [ge stdin] a] {set a [exp $a$o$b]};pu $a
  ```

**You have to use the interactive shell for both solutions.**

I treat the input as list (Tcl uses spaces as delimiter) take the first element and assign it to `a`, then I walk over the rest, taking 2 elements each time, the operator and a second number, apply the operator on `$a` and `$b` and assign the result to `a`. At the end the result is in `a`.

Comment: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Ru4IZV) supports at least stdin.

Comment: Finally, I beat Ruby. Unfortunately [Idone](http://ideone.com/mMzdnP) does not support Tcl 8.6, but I don't need the result of `lmap` so `foreach` is a good replacement.

Answer (score 4):

#### C++0x <strike>205</strike> <strike>203</strike> <strike>198</strike> 194 chars

```
#include<iostream>
#define P [](F l,F r){return l
int main(){typedef float F;F r,v,(*a[])(F,F)={P*r;},P+r;},0,P-r;},0,P/r;}};std::cin>>r;for(char o;std::cin>>o>>v;)r=a[o-42](r,v);std::cout<<r;}
```

Nicely formatted:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    float r,v;
    float (*a[])(float,float)   ={  [](float l,float r){return l*r;},
                                    [](float l,float r){return l+r;},
                                    0,
                                    [](float l,float r){return l-r;},
                                    0,
                                    [](float l,float r){return l/r;}
                                 };

    std::cin>>r;
    for(char o;std::cin>>o>>v;)
        r=a[o-42](r,v);

    std::cout<<r;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell: <strike>124</strike> 114 characters

```
j[o]=o
j(u:m:b:o)=j$show((case m of{"+"->(+);"-"->(-);"*"->(*);"/"->(/)})(read u)(read b)):o
main=interact$j.words
```

A rather straight-forward answer, using pattern matching and a simple case statement for the heavy lifting. Usage:

```
> ./calc <<< "123 - 12 + -12 / 12.124 * 9.99 - 1"
80.57456285054437
```

Comment: Instead of `((case m of{..})(read u)(read b))` you can write `((case m of{..}$read u)$read b)`, 2 characters less.

Answer (score 4):

## C: <strike>111</strike> 108 characters

```
main(c){float a,b;for(scanf("%f ",&a);~scanf("%c%f ",&c,&b);a=c^43?c%5?c%2?a/b:a*b:a-b:a+b);printf("%f",a);}
```

It fulfills all the requirements, usage:

```
> ./calc <<< "-43 - 56 + 14.123 / -13.22"
6.420348
```

Comment: `~scanf` can replace `+1`. Also, `c^45`->`c%5` and `c^42`->`c%2` should work.

Comment: @MDXF not on my machine, it passes every test case here. I'm compiling with Clang on a fairly modern Intel Macbook, and it works smashingly well (I tested it again just now, I copypasted the code from here and just compiled it without any flags). What compiler, processor architecture and OS are you using?

Comment: @Fors I believe I had some odd flags that were inducing strange behavior; my mistake, it's working for me now. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl (97)

```
$b=shift;eval"\$b$r=$s"while($r=shift,$s=shift);print$b
```

read from arguments

```
$b=shift;$b=($r eq'+'?$b+$s:$r eq'-'?$b-$s:$r eq'*'?$b*$s:$b/$s)while($r=shift,$s=shift);print$b;
```

read from input

```
@_=split/ /,<>;$b=shift@_;$b=($r eq'+'?$b+$s:$r eq'-'?$b-$s:$r eq'*'?$b*$s:$b/$s)while($r=shift@_,$s=shift@_);print$b
```

Answer (score 3):

**PostScript (145)**

Another PostScript entry (thanks to luser droog for digging the golfs interesting for PostScript!):

```
[/+{add}/-{sub}/*{mul}/{div}>>begin(%stdin)(r)file
999 string readline
pop{token not{exit}if
count 4 eq{3 1 roll
4 1 roll
cvx exec}if
exch}loop
=
```

Un-golfed:

```
[/+{add}/-{sub}/*{mul}/ {div}>>begin
% Read the input
(%stdin)(r)file 999 string readline pop
{                        % .. string
  token not{exit}if      % .. string token
  % If we have 4 objects on the stack, we have two operands, one operator
  % and the input string. This means, we can calculate now.
  count 4 eq{            % a op string b
    % perform operation a op b = c (where op can be +,-,*,/)
    3 1 roll             % a b op string
    4 1 roll             % string a b op 
    cvx exec             % string c
  }if                    % string token (or c)
  exch                   % token string
}loop
=
```

Comment: You keep beating me! +1 This is very exciting.

Comment: If  you can beat [my crossword](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3877/2381), I'll give you a bounty! N.B. You can only edit 10 times before the post becomes CW and votes don't earn you rep points.

Comment: I keep beating you because I only chose the ones where I *can* beat you ;-). I'm not sure whether I can with the crossword grid. I'll maybe try, but only in a few weeks.

Comment: BTW, what does CW mean?

Comment: Community Wiki. It means the post has been edited so many times it now belongs to the community. Any user can edit it (bypassing the moderator approval required for the usual *suggested* edits), and no more points. So whatever you do, stop on Rev 9. I almost blew it on the guitar tab one.

Comment: Ignore all that CW griping. [They fixed it!](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/238/please-raise-or-remove-cw-limits-on-code-golf-se-site?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

## Python - 308

```
import sys;i=sys.argv[1].split();o=[];s=[];a=o.append;b=s.pop;c=s.append
for t in i:
 if t in"+-*/":
  if s!=[]:a(b())
  c(t)
 else:a(t)
if s!=[]:a(b())
for t in o:
 if t=="+":c(b()+b())
 elif t=="-":m=b();c(b()-m)
 elif t=="*":c(b()*b())
 elif t=="/":m=b();c(b()/m)
 else:c(float(t))
print(b())
```

Readable version:

```
# Infix expression calc

import sys

# Shunting-yard algorithm
input = sys.argv[1].split()
output = []
stack = []

for tkn in input:
    if tkn in "+-*/":
        while stack != []:
            output.append(stack.pop())
        stack.append(tkn)
    else:
        output.append(tkn)

while stack != []:
    output.append(stack.pop())

# Eval postfix notation
for tkn in output:
    if tkn == "+":
        stack.append(stack.pop() + stack.pop())
    elif tkn == "-":
        tmp = stack.pop()
        stack.append(stack.pop() - tmp)
    elif tkn == "*":
        stack.append(stack.pop() * stack.pop())
    elif tkn == "/":
        tmp = stack.pop()
        stack.append(stack.pop()/tmp)
    else:
        stack.append(float(tkn))

print(stack.pop())
```

Takes expression as command-line argument, output on standard output.

Answer (score 2):

### C# <del>(234)</del> <del>(231)</del> <del>(229)</del> <del>(223)</del> (214)

```
class A{void Main(string[]s){var n=1;var o="";var r=0F;foreach(var t in s){if(n>0){var v=float.Parse(t);if(o=="")r=v;if(o=="+")r+=v;if(o=="-")r-=v;if(o=="*")r*=v;if(o=="/")r/=v;}o=t;n=-n;}System.Console.Write(r);}}
```

---

```
class A{
    void Main(string[] s)
    {
      var n = 1;
      var o = "";
      var r = 0F;

      foreach (var t in s)
      {
        if (n > 0)
        {
          var v = float.Parse(t);
          if (o == "") r = v;
          if (o == "+") r += v;
          if (o == "-") r -= v;
          if (o == "*") r *= v;
          if (o == "/") r /= v;
        }
        o = t;
        n = -n;
      }
      System.Console.Write(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting '0' for '1 + 1'.  [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/FEuUf)

Comment: @Mike Input as arguments, not stdin.

Answer (score 2):

**Postscript (340)**

```
/D<</+{add}/-{sub}/*{mul}/ {div}>>def/eval{/P null def{token not{exit}if exch/rem exch def
dup D exch known{/P load null ne{D/P load get exch/P exch def exec}{/P exch def}ifelse}if
rem}loop/P load null ne{D/P load get exec}if}def {(> )print flush{(%lineedit)(r)file
dup bytesavailable string readline pop eval == flush}stopped{quit}if}loop
```

And a little more readable:

```
%!
/oper<</+{add}/-{sub}/*{mul}/ {div}>>def

/eval{
    /op null def
    {
        token not {exit} if
        exch /rem exch def
        dup oper exch known {
            /op load null ne {
                oper /op load get
                exch /op exch def
                exec
            }{
                /op exch def
            } ifelse
        } if
        rem
    } loop
    /op load null ne { oper /op load get exec } if
} def

{
    (> )print flush
    {
    (%lineedit)(r)file
    dup bytesavailable string readline pop
    eval == flush
    } stopped { quit } if
} loop
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (208 characters compacted)

For clarity, this is the code *before* I compacted it down ([JS-Fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/Td83k/1/)):

```
function math(match, leftDigit, operator, rightDigit, offset, string) {
    var L = parseFloat(leftDigit)
    var R = parseFloat(rightDigit)
    switch (operator)
    {
        case '*': return L*R;
        case '/': return L/R;
        case '+': return L+R;
        case '-': return L-R;
    }
};

str = prompt("Enter some math:", "-2 + 6 / 2 * 8 - 1 / 2.5 - 18").replace(/ /g, "");
var mathRegex = /(\-?\d+\.?\d*)([\*\/\+\-])(\-?\d+\.?\d*)/;
while(mathRegex.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(mathRegex, math);
}
alert(str)
```

Here it is compacted down to 208 characters ([JS-Fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/Td83k/3/)):

```
function m(x,l,o,r){
    L=(f=parseFloat)(l);
    R=f(r);
    return o=='*'?L*R:o=='/'?L/R:o=='+'?L+R:L-R;
};

M=/(\-?\d+\.?\d*)([\*\/\+\-])(\-?\d+\.?\d*)/;
for(s=prompt().replace(/ /g, "");M.test(s);s=s.replace(M,m)){};
alert(s)
```

Since I'm ending lines with semi-colons, all *removable* whitespace was ignored for character counting, but left in for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - 124

```
let p=let f[x]=Just$read x;f(x:o:r)=lookup o[("-",(-)),("+",(+)),("*",(*)),("/",(/))]<*>f r<*>Just(read x)in f.reverse.words
```

The result will be wrapped in `Maybe` monad

```
λ: p"-2 + 6 / 2 * 8 - 1 / 2.5 - 18"
Just (-12.0)
```

Also it requires importing `<*>` from `Control.Applicative`, but imports can be done outside the code, so I hope it's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (87 characters)

```
alert(prompt().split(/ +/).reduce((a,b,i)=>i%2?(o=b,a):o+1-0?a-b*-(o+1):o<'/'?a*b:a/b))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 10, <s>151</s> 145 (as lambda function)

```java
s->{float r=0,t,o=0,q;for(var x:s.split(" ")){if(x.length()>1|(q=x.charAt(0)-43)>4){t=new Float(x);r=o<0?r*t:o<1?r+t:o<3?r-t:r/t;}o=q;}return r;}
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

Lambda function taking a String input and outputting a float.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jU@7csIwEOz9FTdUEmCBeSQMwjBp0oWGkkmhGBtEjASnw3HG8bc78uA6k@aeuzu7Z1Wo8Hz4bJJcOQdvSpsqANCGUsxUksK2XQGy3CqChO0ItTmC49Kf68AXR4p0AlswEEPjwnX1wGI8HtLQ@nqTmUVWKIRy6YS75ppYD3qcVzpjpchTc6QT4@voh93iUiQnhS/ExjycTfl6xiuKTfoFr60qK7nE2K7GG@zT0q6iDQ7aPt1gSEsckaxtfJM1pnRHAyjrRrYmr/eP3JvsvBZWH@Dio3Zx9u@g@CPn7ttRehH2TuLqX5QbZkTCeuEMBjD3nuXfsGcxhxFMxD@gE6/41IKhDwsIIXoQ22nRseugbn4B)

## Java 10, <s>241</s> 235 bytes (as full program with asked I/O)

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){float r=0,t;int o=43,q;for(var x:new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ")){if(x.length()>1|(q=x.charAt(0))>47){t=new Float(x);r=o<43?r*t:o<44?r+t:o<46?r-t:r/t;}o=q;}System.out.print(r);}}
```

Full program taking a String-line through STDIN and outputting to STDOUT.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY/BboJAFEV/5cXVPHVGUNsYEEk3XbUrlk0XExx0KM7I40lpKN9OIenm3rs6J7fUrZbl@WscrWNDhc4NvPcNa7Y5tN6e4aatExmTdZePT419UXnNQEmw5rWfso4LT6LVBF3kzDeUE1E92FYqy7VzhkT207C5KetQOdPxm3VGoGrulWWxgAVibwvRqcq4C18FnsJfUSedyq@aXlgEKPc7PO2x52Tmv85@0WFMiT8GKS058scwpdXcu5QkR7ThePBJHQ//av9gdZ8esCCMh2Ec5RZW8Awb2MISDiAhnLd6mtfhDw)

**Explanation:**

```java
interface M{                  // Class
  static void main(String[]a){//  Mandatory main-method
    float r=0,                //   Result float, starting at 0
          t,                  //   Temp float
          o=0,                //   Operator flag, starting at '+'
          q;                  //   Temp operator flag
    for(var x:new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
                              //   Create an STDIN-reader
               .nextLine()    //   Get the user input
               .split(" ")){  //   Split it on spaces, and loop over it:
      if(x.length()>1         //    If the current String length is larger than 1
                              //    (work-around for negative values)
         |(q=x.charAt(0)-43)>4){
                              //    Or the first character is an operator
                              //    (and set `q` to this first character at the same time)
        t=new Float(x);       //     Convert the String to a float, and set it to `t`
        r=                    //     Change `r` to:
          o<0?                //      If `o` is a '*':
            r*t               //       Multiply `r` by `t`
          :o<1?               //      Else-if `o` is a '+':
            r+t               //       Add `r` and `t` together
          :o<3?               //      Else-if `o` is a '-':
            r-t               //       Subtract `t` from `r`
          :                   //      Else (`o` is a '/'):
            r/t;}             //       Divide `r` by `t`
      o=q;}                   //    And at the end of every iteration: set `o` to `q`
    System.out.print(r);}}    //    Print the result `r` to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#ćs2ôívy`…+-*sk©i-ë®>i+ë®<i*ë/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@Uh7sdHhLYfXllUmPGpYpq2rVZx9aGWm7uHVh9bZZWqDKJtMrcOr9f//1zVS0FYwU9BXMFLQUrBQ0FUwBLH1TEEsCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/5SPtxUaHtxxeW1aZ8KhhmbauVnH2oZWZuodXH1pnl6kNomwytQ6v1v9fCwQ6/6OVdE0UtBVMlXQUlHTN9UwV9BWM9CA8I6C4GYivoKVgoaCrYAiRA7EslGIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
#           # Split the (implicit) input-string by spaces
 ć          # Pop the list, and push the remainder and first item separated to the stack
  s         # Swap so the remainder is at the top of the stack
   2ô       # Split it into parts of size 2 (operator + number pairs)
     í      # Reverse each pair so the numbers are before the operators
v           # Loop over each of the pairs:
 y`         #  Push the number and operator separated to the stack
   …+-*     #  Push a string "+-*"
       sk   #  Get the index of the operator in this string
         ©  #  Store this index in the register (without popping)
   i        #  If the index is 1 (the "-"):
    -       #   Subtract the numbers from each other
   ë®>i     #  Else-if the index is 0 (the "+"):
       +    #   Add the numbers together
   ë®<i     #  Else-if the index is 2 (the "*"):
       *    #   Multiply the numbers with each other
   ë        #  Else (the index is -1, so "/"):
    /       #   Divide the numbers from each other
            # (and output the result implicitly)
```

---

If an `eval` builtin was allowed, this could be an alternative approach (**16 bytes**):

```
#ćs2ôJv…(ÿ)y«}.E
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f@Uh7sdHhLV5ljxqWaRzer1l5aHWtnuv//7pGCtoKZgr6CkYKWgoWCroKhiC2nimIZQEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/5SPtxUaHt3iVPWpYpnF4v2blodW1eq7/df5HK@maKGgrmCrpKCjpmuuZKugrGOlBeEZAcTMQX0FLwUJBV8EQIgdiWSjFAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
#ćs2ô    # Same as above
     J   # Join each operator+number pair together to a single string
v        # Loop over the operator+number strings:
 …(ÿ)    #  Surround the top of the stack in parenthesis
     y«  #  And append the operator+number string
}.E      # After the loop: evaluate the string using a Python-eval
```

This would change `"-2 + 6 / 2 * 8 - 1 / 2.5 - 18"` to `"((((((-2)+6)/2)*8)-1)/2.5)-18"` before using the `eval` builtin (using `.E` directly would give operator precedence of `*/` over `+-`, hence the conversion with parenthesis first).

Answer (score 1):

## ZX81 BASIC (might be cheating, so just for fun/non-competing), ~14 Tokenised BASIC bytes, 6 key entries without *new line* (ZX81 speak for enter)

```
1 INPUT A
2 PRINT A
```

Whilst this does not explicitly use any kind of "eval" functions, ZX81 BASIC evaluates any mathematical expressions in its ROM *if you are inputing to a floating point variable* of which `A` would be (like most 8-bit BASIC variants, string variables will have a `$` at the end of the variable name). So when you enter the program and `RUN` it, you can type like `12+10*6` and this will output `72` (note the ZX81 keyboard has some odd key placements for +, /, - and * etc).

The byte count is as follows: as I recall, each line number is stored as 4 bytes, and `INPUT` is a single token, as is `PRINT` (you cannot free type in ZX81 BASIC to enter BASIC commands, so to enter the `INPUT` command, press I, and to enter the `PRINT` command, press P). I don't recall how many bytes are stored at the end of each BASIC line entered, but let's assume that it is a single byte, hence my estimate of 14 tokenised BASIC bytes. I'll find out the exact number at a later time (if this is not cheating).

You may try this online with the [JtyOne Online ZX81 Emulator](http://www.zx81stuff.org.uk/zx81/jtyone.html) which helpfully has an interactive keyboard below the running emulator.