# Take an input, a formula, and do f(x)

Tags: code-golf, math, parsing

## What I want:

Take an input, *x*

Take a formula. It has to be capable of reading something in the format:

- ax^m + bx^n + cx^o ... where m, n, o and any terms after that can represent any value.
- coefficients, again for any number. For example, 6x^2. (That means 6(x^2))
- Doesn't necessarily have to put up with spaces
- times, divide, plus and minus
- brackets - up to stacking of *5*
- ANY negative numbers
- fractions
- To the power of *x* , these can be integeric (<-- is not a word, but that is the best word I can make up!)
- If x = 5, you can put -x to get -5 and -x^2 is -(x^2). You could use (-x)^2

After it interprets the formula, it has to plug *x* into the function, then output the value.

### The Challenge:

- Do it in as less bytes as possible
- The lowest number of bytes wins!

#### Note: I feel that I have included everything here, but if I haven't please comment below, and I will answer it within the next 30 minutes!

## Example

Key:
bp = Background Process

- Give me an input, (x)

4

- Give me a formula:

2^x

- (bp) So I have to do 2 to the power of x, which is 2^4, which is 16
- Output: 16

Comment: >Something in the form of ax means a*x

Comment: Does 6-x^2 mean 6 * -(x^2) or 6 * ((-x)^2)?

Comment: I'm really not sure as to what this challenge is asking, could you at least add some test-cases?

Comment: @StephenS , it says 6x^2. Where did you get the '-' from?

Comment: @Mayube I don't understand.

Comment: "ANY negative numbers" - can you not negate variables?

Comment: @simplest_mathematics test cases are inputs with expected outputs

Comment: @StephenS What does that mean? (The 1st comment)

Comment: This badly needs a specification of exactly what format the input can appear in. It starts off by implying that we're reading in a polynomial, but then why would we need brackets nested to depth 5? Also, is this meant to be a [tag:parsing] challenge? Or are you expecting answers based on `eval`?

Comment: @simplest_mathematics if I have variable x, can I say -x? If x is 5, -x is -5.

Comment: @StephenS , correct

Comment: @simplest_mathematics so if x = 5, what does -x^2 equal?

Comment: [Very closely related, almost duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/617/62131). I'm not sure that adapting the answers to include the use of `x` would make a significant change to the solutions.

Comment: @ais523 , SO does this count as a calculator?

Comment: @simplest_mathematics: Don't look at the name, look at the definition of the challenge. It's very similar to this one, and many answers from it might be adaptable to here.

Comment: @ais523 This one doesn't reqire spaces between characters, making it more feasible for more languages, though.

Comment: @ScottMilner: If I thought it was an exact duplicate I'd have thrown a close vote on. (And given that I got dupehammer rights yesterday, it'd close the challenge by itself.) I don't think it's *quite* close enough to do that, but it's certainly close enough to make people aware of the possibility.

Answer (score 3):

## TI BASIC, 6 bytes

This might change, since the rules are still not totally stable, but I wanted to post this while I could.

```
:Prompt X,F
:F
```

Asks for `X`, then parses whatever formula is put into `F` and displays it.

If I could assume that `X` was already stored in the memory, it would be

## <s>TI BASIC (maybe), 0 bytes</s>

<s>Is this ok?</s>Guess not. :-(

Comment: How do I test this?

Comment: @simplest_mathematics If you have a TI-83/84 calculator, you can create a new program and plug it in. If not, you can find emulators online.

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: A blank code block is `<pre></pre>`. However, I'm pretty sure the second answer won't work because it would need to take input with `X=` preceding it, which means you're taking input via a variable, something that's not allowed by default on PPCG.

Comment: TI BASIC is the programming language of TI 83/84 graphing calculators. You can create full programs in this language. You can find more information [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/home)