# Sigmafy the expression

Tags: code-golf, math, number, arithmetic

For those who didn't know, **[Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma)**  is a Greek letter which is heavily used in mathematics as the summation sign. Given a string representing an expression depending on \$k\$ that we will denote \$E(k)\$, compute the sum of the results for \$E(k)\$, for each \$k\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}\$. Concisely, you should find \$S\$ such that:

$$S=\sum^5_{k=1}E(k)$$

An example of an expression: \$E(k)=\frac k 2 + k^2\$

---

#### Specs

- You are guaranteed:

  - that the expression is valid, so it contains no errors, and that it's dependent of the syntax chosen (e.g: if you only support `2*k`, there will be no `2k`)
  - to only have defined values amongst your results, so no values like `1/0`, `inf` or `nan` will appear
- You can assume that the expression above is fitting the limits of the programming language of your choice, so it won't result in overflows or any other limit-related errors
- Any other non-whitespace ASCII Character instead of `k` can be chosen
- Your program **must** support the following operations:

  - addition (`+`, `plus()`,`add()`,`sum()`)
  - subtraction (`-`, `minus()`, `subtract()`)
  - exponentiation (`**`,`^`,`pow()` or others, should be specified), with support to negative bases and exponents
  - square root in the form of `sqrt(k)`, `k^0.5`, `k**0.5`, or however else you wish
  - multiplication and division
- The submission can either be a full program or a function, while mentioning its usage
- Any trailing / leading whitespace is allowed when outputting
- Minimum precision: 2 decimal places

#### Test Cases (with `k`)

```
+---------------+--------------+   
|  Input = E(k) |    Output    |
|---------------+--------------|
|2*k            | 30           |
|---------------+--------------|
|sqrt(k)        | 8.38         | (* with minimum decimal precision)
|---------------+--------------|
|k+k/2+k**2     | 77.5         |
|---------------+--------------|
|k**2           | 55           |
+---------------+--------------+
```

The score will be the number of bytes (of the source + compiler flags). The lowest scoring valid submission wins, while taking note that [these loopholes](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are strictly forbidden. **[Here](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqjgalVcmqsRnVqWmKNRXFKk4aqpV5RakJOYnKqhnq2uAxLK1NTUVEjLL1LIVMjMUyhKzEtP1TDUMdOM1fxfUJSZV6KRBlSqpWWkrqnJhRDQBgoZ6JmiCuoaoivSN9LG1KulZYwqoG8MVGmCMPI/AA)** is a Python pseudo-code, to make things clearer.

Comment: Can we take `plus()` instead of `+`? (Same questions for all other operators too)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, `plus()`,`add()`,`sum()` and equivalents are allowed. See the edit.

Comment: No, you may only take the expression once, @ComradeSparklePony

Comment: Can we use postfix notation? For example, test case 3 from the top would be something like: `N N2/+N2**+`.

Comment: That's very strange, but it is allowed as long as you clearly state the "format" of `E(x)` @ComradeSparklePony

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder That isn't very strange. There are languages which use the postfix notation, as well as languages which use the prefix notation. Putting those expressing in our native notation makes `eval` easier.

Comment: @LeakyNun yes, I have totally understood the purpose, and thus have allowed it, but I said that it's strange for the tester, not to the author.

Comment: Does the program need to support multiplication and division? It's in the test cases, but not in the specs.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry @pajonk yes, it must.

Comment: [Borderline dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/617/194)

Comment: Do you really think this is a dupe @PeterTaylor ? I would say it is loosely related.

Comment: IMO the hard work is parsing the expression. Substituting a value for the string `k` and looping from 1 to 5 are pretty trivial in comparison. The main reason I didn't actually vote to close is that it's not clear what range of parameters for `^` the other question requires, so I don't know whether `sqrt` is covered.

Comment: @PeterTaylor that one also restricts using `eval`, that's why I say it is just related

Comment: Can we take something like `expression(k+k/2+k**2)` as input instead of a string?

Comment: @JayCe Like taking a black-box function representing the expression `E(k)` and just doing `sum(map(E,1...5))` (pseudo-code)? If so, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
vÐ€5S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@192eMKjpjWmwf8PtwPp/4b/o7k4lR7uWKKkA6QP7QVT2h7ahzZBBDYpccUCAA)

Input a valid Jelly monadic chain (I golfed them down in my link).

### How it works

```
vÐ€5S
 Ð€     for each of ...
   5        5 (implicitly converted to [1,2,3,4,5]), ...
v           evaluate the input with the above as argument
    S   and find the sum
```

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to Ian Miller for saving 3 bytes.*

*Thanks to LegionMammal978 for saving 1 byte.*

```
#~NSum~{k,5}&
```

The input should be an actual expression containing `k`, e.g.:

```
#~NSum~{k,5}&[Sqrt[k]^3+4]
```

Comment: I should have guessed that Mathematica had built-ins for this

Comment: Mathematica *always* has built-ins for situations. :P

Comment: You don't need the `1,` in it for `Sum`.

Comment: In fact it can shorten to `N@#~Sum~{k,5}&`

Comment: @IanMiller Oh right, of course. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that `#~NSum~{k,5}&` should also work.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 It does, thank you. :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

3 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

Eval scope tricks \o/

```python
f=lambda s,k=5:k and eval(s)+f(s,k-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqFCsk21rapWtkJiXopBalpijUaypnaYBFNU11PxfUJSZV6KRpqFkpJWtpKnJBedna2kZ6JmiCmln6xtpAyWM0FWCBP4DAA)

Uses `k**0.5` instead of `sqrt(k)`.

Comment: Is it allowed to answer a question that fast? o_O

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>31</s> 30 bytes

Uses `k**0.5` for `sqrt(k)`.

```js
f=(e,k=6)=>--k&&f(e,k)+eval(e)

console.log(f("2*k"))
console.log(f("k**0.5"))
console.log(f("k+k/2+k**2"))
console.log(f("k**2"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#@59mq5Gqk21rpmlrp6ubraaWBuJqaqeWJeZopGpycSXn5xXn56Tq5eSna6RpKBlpZStpaqKLZmtpGeiZYpPQztY30gZKG2HXBRL@/x8A)

Comment: Ninjaed again! Nicely done.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
6G¹.VO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@2/mfminXpj///9@Cn5G@tp@RrnaAA)

Input is in postfix notation, and **uses the variable N**. 05AB1E is a stack-based language, so only postfix notation works.

Format of `E(N)`: write the number(s) you want to do the operation with, and then write the sign of the operation. For example, `3+4` would be `3 4+`, `3*4+2*3` would be `3 4* 2 3* +`. Also note that this uses `t` instead of `sqrt`, and `m` instead of `**`, so `sqrt(N)` would be `Nt`.

**Explanation:**

```
6G¹.VO
6G     For N in range(1,6). This includes [1,2,3,4,5].
  ¹.V  Read and eval input.
     O Sum results.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>50</s> <s>46</s> <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```matlab
@(d)eval(["k=1:5;sum(" d 41])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7ON@e@gkaKZWpaYoxGtlG1raGVqXVyaq6GkkKJgYhir@T9NQ8lITytbSZMLyCouLCrRyNaEcLK1s/WNtLP14oygfDDrPwA)

Exponentiation is denoted with the caret `.^` and multiplication is denoted with `.*`.

This declares an anonymous function that takes in argument `d`. It sets `k` to be equal to the range `1:5` and sums the evaluated `d` and returns it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 10 bytes

```
6ÆK=XOxUÃx
```

Input string should have variable as an uppercase `K`. `sqrt(K)` should be inputted as `K**0.5`.

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=NsZLPVhPeFXDeA==&input=IksrSy8yK0sqKjIi)

### Explanation

`eval` scope didn't work in my favor; had to redefine the counting variable `X` as a global `K`.

```
6ÆK=XOxUÃx      // implicit: U = input string
6oXYZ{K=XOxU} x // expanded

6oXYZ{      }   // create array [0, 6) and map to function:
      K=X       //   redefine the array value to global K
         OxU    //   eval the input string
              x // sum the resulting array
```

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if transpiling `Ox` directly to `eval(` would help with that...

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```matlab
@(f)sum(inline(f)(1:5))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gkaZZXJqrkZmXk5mXCuRoGFqZamr@LyjKzCtJ01BSzYzJU9JRSMwr1lA30spW19S05sImV1xYVKKRrYlTPls7W99IO1svzgi3EqjkfwA)

Exponentiation is denoted as `.^`

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
+/⍎⎕⊣k←⍳5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9TRnvZfW/9Rb9@jvqmPuhZnP2qb8Kh3s@n/Rx3t/9O41I0OT89W5wIysrX0TCEMbY3sw9uNNLWztYygMkbqAA)

Addition is `+`, subtraction is `-`, multiplication is `×`, division is `÷` exponentiation is `*` and execution is right to left, so use `()` to group expressions.

Input is in terms of `k`.

#### Explanation

```apl
k←⍳5                    Set k to be equal to the vector 1 2 3 4 5
⊣                       The left argument:
+/                      Sum of
⍎⎕                      The evaluated input (the eval returns an array because k is an array)
```

---

And here's a solution that takes trains as input (like the Jelly answer): [`+/(⍎⎕)¨⍳5`](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#e9TRnvZfW1/jUW/fo76pmodWPOrdbPr/UUf7/zQudaPD0x91LVLnAjL1TLUe9a6A8YC0tobR4e0QIU1tI2RJOAcA).

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 55 bytes

```
(defun f(x)#.(read))(print(+(f 1)(f 2)(f 3)(f 4)(f 5)))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#@6@RkppWmqeQplGhqaynUZSamKKpqVFQlJlXoqGtkaZgqAkkjECEMYgwARGmmpqa//9raClUAGUA)

```
Example input - output: 
(* x 2) - 30 
(sqrt x) - 8.382333 
(+ (/ x 2) x (expt x 2)) - 155/2 
(expt x 2) - 55
```

different, longer (58 bytes) version - starts getting shorter if you do sumation from 1 to 7.

```
(print #.`(+,@(mapcar #'(lambda(x)#.(read))'(1 2 3 4 5))))
```

yet another and longer method (<s>65</s> 64 bytes) - doesn't define function - just inserts your expression into a loop. Should get shorter for bigger sums.

```
(setf a(read)b 0)(loop as x from 1 to 5 do(incf b #.a))(print b)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, <s>202</s> 184 bytes

```swift
import Foundation;func s(i:String){print([1,2,3,4,5].map{NSExpression(format:i.replacingOccurrences(of:"k",with:"\($0).0")).expressionValue(with:nil,context:nil)as!Float}.reduce(0,+))}
```

For some reason this will only run locally :(.

Here is an explanation of what I am doing:

```swift
import Foundation // Import the Foundation module

func s(i:String){ // Create a function that takes in a String and returns a Float

    print( // Print the result of the follow algorithm to strdout

        [1,2,3,4,5].map{ //Conduct the follow code on numbers 1 - 5

            NSExpression(format: // Create an expression with the following String and return it 

            i.replacingOccurrences(of:"k",with:"\($0).0")) // Create a string replacing all ocurrances of 'k' in `i` with the current Float from the map

           .expressionValue(with:nil,context:nil)as!Float // Get the resulting value of the expression

       }.reduce(0,+) // Add the result of all the expressions together
    )
}
```

Thanks to @Mr. Xcoder for saving 15 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 12 bytes

```
Σ(expr(Ans),K,1,5
```

Call with `"string":prgmNAME`, where `string` is any valid TI-Basic expression of `K`.

Comment: Interesting solution of the same length: `Ans->u:sum(u(1,5`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 16 bytes

```
5~>[@k#~]2/"!sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#q1bM@29aZxftkK1cF2ukr6RYXJr7P08hRkFHQaUotaBIITexQEFdwdYOSGTlZ@Yp5JeWKNRycWlwKahnKxgpaKmDGcWFRSUQFkhQH0zGKWgraKtD1cWpc2kCTQWa9h8A)

`5~>` is a range from 1 to 5 incluive. `2/` makes a func dyadic, `"` is pair-wise, and `!` is execute. This thus maps the range `[1, 5]` with the input, which is then evaluated after defining the range member to be `k`. Then, the results are summed.

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>31</s> 24 bytes

```
?sa1k[lax+Kd1+k5>p]dspxp
```

The input must be given in reverse-Polish notation (also known as postfix notation) and enclosed in square brackets (`[]`) with:

- `K` replacing `k` as the parameter;
- `+` representing addition;
- `-` representing subtraction and `_` followed by any number representing a negative number;
- `*` representing multiplication;
- `/` representing division;
- `^` representing exponentiation;
- `v` representing the square-root.

For example, `-2*k+k+3*k**2+k**0.5-k/2` would be input as `[_2K*K+K2^3*+Kv+K2/-]`. This takes due advantage of the fact that `K` is a `dc` command which returns the current precision (initially set to `1`). Therefore, by the end, this returns the output with a precision of `6`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@29fnGiYHZ2TWKHtnWKonW1qVxCbUlxQUfD/f7S3kVbs17x83eTE5IxUAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 58 bytes

```
proc S {f s\ 0} {time {incr k
set s [expr $s+$f]} 5
set s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCsIwEIThe55iDnvQFLQEfJIe1YOEBMq2GrNbEEKePQ31Mj/M4VO/tJbyx2NCiZAHxoqi8xpQ5rfPYCNBIbiHX8ogGSg@K27/t7ZlfSVEFGeJId@sJ@IziAfiq7uMPdY6HNtdkzbt1ISOmNp2)

If it only worked with integers, I could golf it more!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
k=1:5;sum(eval(parse(t=scan(,""))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qvnFaal1ySmZ@nUaGTbWtoZapZXJqrkVqWmKNRkFhUnKpRYluhqanJpZymoWSkla0EYRUXFpVoZGtCedna2fpG2tlaWkYwAQjzP9hAawwDi5MT8zR0lJSA5mr@B6nl@g8A)

TIO link includes a function solution as well (38 bytes)