# Programming with Bits and Bytes

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, bitwise

In this challenge you are going to write an interpreter for a simple language I've made up. The language is based on a single accumulator A, which is exactly one byte in length. At the start of a program, A = 0. These are the languages instructions:

### `!`: Inversion

This instruction simply inverts every bit of the accumulator. Every zero becomes a one and every one becomes a zero. Simple!

### `>`: Shift Right

This instruction shifts every bit in A one place to the right. The leftmost bit becomes a zero and the rightmost bit is discarded.

### `<`: Shift Left

This instruction shifts every bit in A one place to the left. The rightmost bit becomes a zero and the leftmost bit is discarded.

### `@`: Swap Nybbles

This instruction swaps the top four bits of A with the bottom four bits. For example, If A is `01101010` and you execute `@`, A will be `10100110`:

```
 ____________________
 |                  |
0110 1010    1010 0110
      |_______|
```

That's all the instructions! Simple, right?

## Rules

- Your program must accept input *once* at the beginning. This will be a line of code. This is *not* an interactive interpreter! You can only accept input once and do not have to loop back to the start once that line has been executed.
- Your program must evaluate said input. Every character that is not mentioned above is ignored.
- Your program should then print out the final value of the accumulator, in decimal.
- Usual rules for valid programming languages apply.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), smallest byte count wins.

Here are some small programs to test out your submissions. Before the arrow is the code, after it is the expected result:

- `!` -> `255`
- `!>>` -> `63`
- `!<@` -> `239`
- `!nop!&6*!` -> `255`

Enjoy!

Comment: I'm presuming from `! -> 255` that we're to use 8 bits per byte here?  The question isn't explicit.

Comment: @TobySpeight A byte, by definition, is 8 bits.

Answer (score 15):

## Pyth, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
u%@[t_G/G2yGi_jGJ16JG)x"!><@"H256z0
```

[Test harness](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%25%40%5Bt_G%2FG2yGi_jGJ16JG%29x%22%21%3E%3C%40%22H256z0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%21%0A%21%3E%3E%0A%21%3C%40%0A%21%3C%26&debug=0)

The internal representation of the accumulator is an integer. This integer is mod-ed by 256 on each iteration, as desired. The operations performed are `-G-1`, `G/2`, `G*2` and `G` converted to base 16, reversed, and converted back to base 10, where `G` is the accumulator.

I missed the line about ignoring everything else. This has been remedied. Thanks, @Dennis.

Comment: So `-G-1` is shorter than `~G` in Pyth? I somewhat doubt that.

Comment: The code in question is actually `t_G`, where `_` is negation and `t` is `-1`. In Pyth, `~` means something totally different.

Comment: I meant Python `~` (bitwise NOT)

Comment: @CalculatorFeline My point was there is no 1-character function with that effect in Pyth, so the above code (at least for that operation) is as good as it's going to get.

Answer (score 13):

## C, 96

Assuming ASCII (or compatible) input:

```
a;main(c){while(c=getchar()+1)a=(c^34?c^61?c^63?c^65?a:a*257/16:a/2:a*2:~a)&255;printf("%u",a);}
```

**Tidier:**

```
a;
main(c){
  while(c=getchar()+1)
    a=(c^34?
      c^61?
        c^63?
          c^65?
            a
          :
            a*257/16
        :
          a/2
      :a*2:~a
    )&255;
  printf("%u",a);
}
```

Basically it's just a collection of nested ternary expressions. I'm incrementing the value obtained from `getchar()` so that an EOF (-1) results in a value of zero and the program exits.

[**(ideone link)**](http://ideone.com/x3geGw)

Comment: I tried the challenge myself and I wrote almost exactly the same code. Btw. your program doesn't drop the bit when shifting upwards (input: `!<>` should result in `127` and not `255`). Either define your `a` as `char`, or use the line `a&=255` (and use `%u`) to get the correct effect. Also you can shorten your negation `a^255` to `~a`. `a>>4&15` is also shorter than your `(a&240)/16`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Turns out it was more efficient to mask out the lower 8 bits at each iteration.

Comment: In this case you can even use the format string `%u` instead of `%hhu`

Comment: I just saw it now, but you can also use `a/16|a*16` instead of `a/16|(a&15)*16`. The few bits on top get removed by the `&255`.

Comment: A tiny improvement: `a*257/16` is one byte shorter than `a/16|a*16`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Nice one, thanks!

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcdNCsIwEAbQs1hQZlqlNG0qZCz1Kh9D/xatEuJKzNUj2Tx4eltUU4Ls2A5S/s4vT6JDXKagKzyxMAbSqu1Grfom02bsCIfS2Hvd9A61yXERfDHWyttvR5ipOH@KK1h@KZ0ezz8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 11):

## Python 3, 133 bytes

Uses a dictionary to make up for a lack of switch-case syntax in Python. [See more here](http://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html).

```py
a="0"*8
for i in input():a={"!":''.join(str(1-int(b))for b in a),"<":a[1:]+"0",">":"0"+a[:-1],"@":a[4:]+a[:4]}.get(i,a)
print(int(a,2))
```

The accumulator is a string which is converted into a base 10 number at the end.

#### Example I/O:

```bash
$ python3 bitsnbytes.py
!
255
$ python3 bitsnbytes.py
!>>
63
$ python3 bitsnbytes.py
!<@
239
$ python3 bitsnbytes.py
!nop!&6*!
255
```

Comment: If it was a real, interactive interpreter, it would be `for i in sys.stdin:` :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 I believe you mean if it was interactive; it looks like a real interpreter to me. ;)

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>80</s> <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```
a=>[...a].reduce((p,c)=>c=='!'?p^255:c=='<'?p*2%256:c=='>'?p>>1:c=='@'?p/16|0+p%16*16:p,0)
```

Pretty much as short as it can get. Defines an anonymous function which takes the program as input.

- For `!`, takes `x XOR 255`, as JS's `~` would consider `x` a 32-bit number.
- For `<`, multiplies `x` by 2 and takes the result mod 256.
- For `>`, truly shifts the bits of `x` 1 bit to the right.
- For `@`, floors `x/16` and adds it to `x%16*16`.

Thanks to @vihan for suggesting the use of `reduce` to save a byte.

Comment: You can use `<` to save around 4 bytes. Using reduce *might* also save some bytes

Comment: @vihan Do you mean `<` in place of `==`? If so, that wouldn't work, as no-op characters would incorrectly perform an operation. I used that in my previous, 80-byte solution.

Comment: Isn't ES6 fat arrow standard on PPCG that you have to define it?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja I don't know of any such standard, but if you could point me to a post about one, I'll modify my answer.

Comment: `0+` in `p/16|0+p%16*16` does nothing

Answer (score 9):

## Java (8), <s>514</s> <s>483</s> <s>411</s> <s>366</s> <s>359</s> <s>239</s> <s>224</s> <s>229</s> <s>198</s> <s>194</s> <s>187</s> <s>186</s> <s>184</s> <s>182</s> <s>181</s> <s>180</s> 177 characters

Wow, this has been golfed down a LOT! Thanks to everyone who gave me suggestions! I greatly appreciate it!

```
interface T{static void main(String[]g)throws Exception{int i,a=0;while((i=System.in.read())!=10)a=(i==33?255-a:i==62?a/2:i==60?a*2:i==64?a>>4|a<<4:a)%256;System.out.print(a);}}
```

Golfed 31 (!) bytes by optimizing the nibble swap with bitwise operations as opposed to lengthy `Integer.???` methods.

Golfed 72 (!!!!) chars by removing the unnecessary string created to swap nibbles. Much better than before!?

Golfed 45 (!!) chars by removing use of `java.util.Scanner` and reading from `System.in` directly. Note that now that the lambda expression is gone, Java 8 is no longer required! Just merely Java 1 would do!

Golfed 7 chars by making class `(default)` (removed `public` keyword), thanks to @bmarks

Golfed 120 (!!!!!!!) chars by turning all those lengthy `Integer` class operations in the bit flipping to `255 - a`. Now that's much shorter!

Golfed 15 (!) chars by converting shifts to multiplication and division, removing the braces from the while statement, and making `a` local within the `main` method.

Ungolfed 9 =( chars because of a problem with the left shift not discarding the leftmost byte. Therefore, I now do `mod (256)`. The right shift will make the resulting number one bit shorter than before, so there is no need to use `mod` on right shift. My nibble-swap thing will swap the last 4 bits and the second-last nibble, and the `and (&)` truncates all other bits. My inversion program doesn't cause any problems if the original number is less than 256.

Golfed <s>31</s> 35 chars thanks to @Geobits by converting `switch` statement to a lot of ternary statements, and also converting chars to ints, shortening the literals.

Golfed 7 chars by removing unnecessary `&240` in the nibble swap (`(a&240)>>4` to `a>>4` and converting `(a&15)<<4` to `a<<4&240`. The last change only golfed one character though.

Golfed 1 char by removing unnecessary `=` in `a /= 2`, because `a = a /= 2` is equivalent to `a = a / 2`.

Golfed 2 chars by turning `println` to `print`.

Golfed 2 chars by removing accidental `a=` in `a=255-a` (`a=a=255-a` is equivalent to `a=255-a`)

Golfed 1 char by turning `a<<4&240` into `a%16<<4`.

Golfed 1 char by adding brackets to the outside of the ternary statement and doing `%256`. That way, the `%16` is unnecessary in the left-shift part of the nibble swap. The brackets add 2 chars and the `%16` saves 3 chars.

Golfed 3 chars by changing `class` to `interface` and removing `public` using Java 8's static interface method feature. Thanks to @TheNumberOne (no comment, but find his answer on "Tips for golfing in Java"

Comment: I don't think the class has to be public.
Also, I think if you make a an Integer instead of an int, you could do a.parseInt, a.toString, etc. instead of Integer.parseInt,Integer.toString, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion; I'm going to remove all `Integer` class methods though.

Comment: Perhaps you can do while((i=System.in.read())>10) instead of !=10 to save a byte?

Comment: Good idea, but then anything below 10 will cause the program to terminate, and I'm supposed to ignore other characters, not make then the end of the world (or at least my program:)) I'll consider it though; perhaps there are no valid ascii characters below 10.

Comment: Ah, indeed my suspicions were correct. A tabulator is `(char) 9`.

Comment: It's *almost* never worth it to use a `switch` while golfing. The `case`/`break` are just too long. You should be able to save a bunch by making the whole thing a ternary; something like `a=i=='!'?255-a:i==62?a/2:i=='<'?a*2%256:i=='@'?(a&240)>>4|(a&15)<<4:a;`

Comment: @Geobits Thanks a lot! You saved me 31 characters!

Comment: Whoops, I mean 35 characters.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, 37 bytes

```
0q{"!><@"#"~ 2/ 2* GmdG*+ "S/=~255&}/
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0q%7B%22!%3E%3C%40%22%23%22~%202%2F%202*%20GmdG*%2B%20%22S%2F%3D~255%26%7D%2F&input=!%3C%40).

#### How it works

```
0                   e# Push 0 (accumulator).
q                   e# Read from STDIN.
{                   e# For each character in the input:
  "!><@"#           e#   Find its index in "!><@" (-1 if not found).
  "~ 2/ 2* GmdG*+ " e#   Push that string.
  S/                e#   Split at spaces to push ["~" "2/" "2*" "GmdG*+" ""].
                    e#     "~"      : signed 64-bit bitwise NOT
                    e#     "2/"     : divide by 2
                    e#     "2*"     : multiply by 2
                    e#     "GmdG*+" : (x) -> (x/16) (x%16) -> (16(x%16) + (x/16))
                    e#     ""       : NOOP
  =~                e#  Select the corresponding string and evaluate it.
  255&              e#  Zero all but the 8 least significant bits.
}/                  e#
```

Answer (score 7):

### Rust, <s>121</s> 115 bytes

```rust
fn r(s:&str)->u8{let mut n=0u8;for t in s.chars(){match t{'!'=>n=!n,'>'=>n/=2,'<'=>n<<=1,'@'=>n=n>>4|n<<4,_=>()}}n}
```

Sample run:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", r("!"));    //=> 255
    println!("{}", r("!>>"));  //=> 63
    println!("{}", r("!<@"));  //=> 239
}
```

Ungolfed:

```rust
fn run_ungolfed(s: &str) -> u8 {
    let mut n = 0u8;
    for t in s.chars() {
        match t {
            '!' => n = !n,
            '>' => n >>= 1,
            '<' => n <<= 1,
            '@' => n = (n >> 4) | (n & 15) << 4,
            _ => ()
        }
    }
    n
}
```

Surprisingly short for Rust. Nothing else really interesting other than the fact that [I learned more precedence rules today](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#operator-precedence)—who knew `(a>>b)|c` is the same as `a>>b|c`?

Shaved off a byte by changing `n>>=1` to `n/=2`; however, the same cannot be done with multiplication, because arithmetic overflow is a panic (i.e. crash) in Rust.

Comment: The precedence thing makes sense when you convince yourself that `>>` is *sort* of like division and `|` is *sort* of like addition.

Answer (score 7):

## HP 41C/CV/CX (77 bytes, 42 steps)

Purely for giggles, here it is for the HP 41C/CV/CX calculator. (Requires either the Extended Functions module, or a 41CX for the ATOX function.)

Put your program into the Alpha register, which is a little tricky, as there's no way to enter ! or @ directly from the keyboard (use XTOA with the ASCII codes 33 and 64 respectively to append them).

Steps 08 and 10 allow for ignoring invalid opcodes; remove them to save 2 steps, but the program will crash on invalid input.

```
01 LBL"BB
02 0
03 LBL A
04 ATOX
05 X=0?
06 GTO E
07 X<>Y
08 SF 25
09 XEQ IND Y
10 CF 25
11 GTO A
12 LBL 33
13 255
14 X<>Y
15 -
16 RTN
17 LBL 60
18 2
19 *
20 256
21 MOD
22 RTN
23 LBL 62
24 2
25 /
26 INT
27 RTN
28 LBL 64
29 RCL X
30 16
31 /
32 INT
33 X<>Y
34 16
35 *
36 256
37 MOD
38 +
39 RTN
40 LBL E
41 RDN
42 RTN
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 79 bytes

I realized that I have done something [very similar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8747/4372) to this in Python earlier. This is just a port of [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57224/4372), but it is incidentally the shortest Python answer as of now :D

```
a=0
for i in raw_input():a=[~a,a/2,a*2,a*16+a/16,a]["!><@".find(i)]&255
print a
```

The difference from the Ruby version is that this one doesn't ignore invalid instructions while iterating over the input. Instead I take advantage of the fact that Python tends to return `-1` instead of `nil` when there is no match -- The current value of `a` is appended to the back of the result array, so that all invalid instructions maps to the same, unchanged value.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>124</s> <s>94</s> 93 bytes

```python
a=0
for i in input():
 if i in"!><@":a=(i=='!')*(255-a)+(i==">")*a//2+(i=="<")*(a+a)%256+(i=="@")*(16*(a%16)+a//16)
print(a)
```

"!" is same as subtracting from 255.
"<" is same as multiplying by 2. But 8 bit register means mod 256.
">" is same as integer division by 2.
"@" means shifting last 4 bits (`a%16`) by 4 bits(`*16`) and adding the first four bits(`a/16`).

**EDIT (read shameless copying)**
Saw the other answer in python (by Beta decay). It uses a really effective way to simulate switch cases using dictionary. Using that we can write

```python
a=0
for i in input():a={"!":255-a,"<":a<<1&255,">":a//2,"@":(a%16)<<4+a>>4}.get(i,a)
print(a)
```

Thanks, Beta Decay.

Comment: No matter what operation you do, you have to reduce mod `256` right?  So why not do that at the end: `a={"!":255-a,"<":a*2,">":a//2,"@":(a%16)<<4+a>>4}.get(i,a)%256`.  This immediately saves you a byte (because you'll do `a*2` instead of `a<<1`)...but @daniero's answer also shows that if you do it this way then `(a%16)<<4` can be shortened to just `a<<4`, because any bit 16 or larger will be eliminated once you multiply it by 16 and reduce it mod 256. Nice! Also, you can now replace `255-a` by `-1-a`...or better, by just `~a`.  Altogether, these suggestions should save you 9 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 89 bytes

```
a#'!'=255-a
a#'>'=div a 2
a#'<'=mod(a*2)256
a#'@'=mod(a*16)256+div a 16
a#_=a
f=foldl(#)0
```

Usage example: `f "!>>"` -> `63`

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <del>81</del> 73 bytes

So much simpler -- no eval! For each valid character in the input, it evaluates each instruction, and finds the appropriate instruction through the index of `$&` (the current character in the input).

```
a=0
gets.scan(/[!><@]/){a=[~a,a/2,a*2,a*16+a/16]["!><@".index$&]&255}
p a
```

Comment: That's genius. Much shorter that any other way. 2 upvotes by me!

Comment: How can you double upvote...?

Comment: @JamesSmith He's probably referring to this and my [python answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57238/4372) :)

Comment: @danerio I see.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 127 bytes

Edit: shorting, thanks @Jakube

Edit2: fix, thanks @Anachor

```
a=0
for i in input():a=(a^255if i=="!"else a>>1if i==">"else a<<1if i=="<"else(a&15)<<4|(a&240)>>4if i=="@"else a)&255
print(a)
```

Comment: Maybe this is because windows' new line. That's plus two bytes. I'll use that byte counter next time. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Note that this doesn't discard the leftmost bit when left shifting, so `!<` gives `510` while it should be `254`

Comment: I hope now it does. Sorry for my mistakes, this is my first "golf" challenge.

Answer (score 3):

### Rust, 111 bytes

More of a comment on @Doorknob's answer, but I don't have any rep for comments as I just created an account.

One can shave 10 bytes off his Rust solution with the following:

```rust
fn r(s:&str)->u8{let mut n=0u8;for t in s.chars(){n=match t{'!'=>!n,'>'=>n>>1,'<'=>n<<1,'@'=>n>>4|n<<4,_=>n}}n}
```

Comment: I thought we could get even shorter using fold (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) but surprisingly makes it a tad longer.

Answer (score 3):

## Ceylon, <s>297</s> 290

```
shared void y(){value t=process.readLine()else"";variable Byte a=0.byte;for(c in t){switch(c)case('!'){a=a.not;}case('>'){a=a.rightLogicalShift(1);}case('<'){a=a.leftLogicalShift(1);}case('@'){a=a.and(#f0.byte).rightLogicalShift(4).xor(a.and(#f.byte).leftLogicalShift(4));}else{}}print(a);}
```

Formatted:

```
shared void y() {
    value t = process.readLine() else "";
    variable Byte a = 0.byte;
    for (c in t) { switch (c)
        case ('!') { a = a.not; }
        case ('>') { a = a.rightLogicalShift(1); }
        case ('<') { a = a.leftLogicalShift(1); }
        case ('@') { a = a.and(#f0.byte).rightLogicalShift(4).xor(a.and(#f.byte).leftLogicalShift(4)); }
        else {} }
    print(a);
}
```

`#f` and `#f0` are hexadecimal numbers for the nibbles, `.byte` converts an integer into a byte. I'm lucky that Byte's `.string` attribute already uses the unsigned representation of a byte.
Ceylon also features a switch statement without fall-through, and a string is a list of characters, which can be iterated.

I also tried to cut those long shift method names down by using an aliasing import, but this actually becomes 7 bytes longer:

```
import ceylon.language{Byte{r=rightLogicalShift,l=leftLogicalShift}}shared void x(){value t=process.readLine()else"";variable Byte a=0.byte;for(c in t){switch(c)case('!'){a=a.not;}case('>'){a=a.r(1);}case('<'){a=a.l(1);}case('@'){a=a.and(#f0.byte).r(4).xor(a.and(#f.byte).l(4));}else{}}print(a);}
```

Formatted:

```
import ceylon.language {
    Byte {
        r=rightLogicalShift,
        l=leftLogicalShift
    }
}
shared void x() {
    value t = process.readLine() else "";
    variable Byte a = 0.byte;
    for (c in t) {
        switch (c)
        case ('!') { a = a.not; }
        case ('>') { a = a.r(1); }
        case ('<') { a = a.l(1); }
        case ('@') { a = a.and(#f0.byte).r(4).xor(a.and(#f.byte).l(4)); }
        else {}
    }
    print(a);
}
```

This might be useful if we need those methods a bit more often.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 <s>81</s>

As an unnamed function returning the accumulator value

This is a porting of the super clever answers by @daniero (that have way too few upvotes)

Bonus: you *can* pass an initial value of the accumulator. If not passed, starting value is 0 as by specific.

```
(p,a)=>(p.replace(/[!<>@]/g,i=>a=(i<'<'?~a:i<'>'?a*2:i<'@'?a/2:a*257/16)&255),a)
```

Test running the snippet below in any EcmaScript 6 browser (I tested in Firefox)

```js
f=(p,a)=>[...p].map(c=>a=255&[a,~a,a*2,a/2,a*257/16][1+'!<>@'.indexOf(c)])|a

// TEST
out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

function go(x) { out(x+' -> '+f(x)) }

go('!'),go('!>>'),go('!<@'),go('!nop!&6*!')

// LESS GOLFED
F=(p,a)=>// a as a parameter, if not passed its value starts as undefined, then becomes NaN, but the operators '&' and '~' treat it as 0
  [...p].map(c => // execute following function for each character p
    a = 255 & // any intermediate result is converted to numeric and truncate to a byte          
   // evaluate all possible results (then choose one bases on the current character)
   [a,   // NOP, if unexpected char 'a' remains the same
    ~a,  // tilde == binary not (will give a result wider than a byte)
    a*2, // < shift left is *2 (can give a result wider than a byte) 
    a/2, // > shift right is /2 (can give a non integer result)
    a *257 / 16  // move nibbles around (will give a result wider than a byte)
   ] // array of all results
   [1+'!<>@'.indexOf(c)] // find index to get the correct result
  ) // end map, returns an array in any case
    // eventually a single element array containg a
  | a // return accumulator
```

```html
Test program:<input id=I><button onclick='go(I.value)'>go</button>
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

### STATA, 197 bytes

```
di _r(a)
gl b=0
forv x=1/`=length("$a")'{
gl c=substr("$a",`x',1)
if"$c"=="!" gl b=255-$b
if"$c"==">" gl b=int($b/2)
if"$c"=="<" gl b=mod($b*2,256)
if"$c"=="@" gl b=mod($b,16)*16+int($b/16)
}
di $b
```

Ungolfed

```
display _request(a) //get the input via prompt and put in var a
global b=0 //initialise A to be 0
forv x=1/`=length("$a")'{ //for loop from 1 to last char in a
global c=substr("$a",`x',1) //get the char at index x in a
if "$c"=="!" global b=255-$b //invert is the same as 255-A
if "$c"==">" global b=int($b/2) //right shift is the same as A/2 (with integer division)
if "$c"=="<" global b=mod($b*2,256) //left shift is the same as A*2%256
if "$c"=="@" global b=mod($b,16)*16+int($b/16) //nibble swap is the same as A%16*16+A/16
}
display $b //display the result of A
```

Does not work with the online interpreter and requires the non-free default interpreter. This would be somewhat easier with actual bitwise operations, but I don't think they're too useful for most of the common uses of STATA.

Comment: Why doesn't the online interpreter work?

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>117</s> <s>94</s> <s>86</s> 73 bytes

```
p->(a=0x0;[a=c==33?~a:c==60?a<<1:c==62?a>>1:c!=64?a:a<<4|a>>4for c=p];1a)
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns an integer. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(p)
    # Initialize the accumulator to 0 as an 8-bit unsigned integer
    a = 0x0

    # Loop over the characters in the input
    for c in p
        a = c == 33 ? ~ a :        # '!'
            c == 60 ? a << 1 :     # '<'
            c == 62 ? a >> 1 :     # '>'
            c != 64 ? a :          # no-op
            a << 4 | a >> 4        # '@'
    end

    # Convert the accumulator to a regular integer and return
    return Int(a)
end
```

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Sp3000 and 13 thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 104

```
[].reduce.call(prompt(),function(a,i){return(i=='!'?~a:i=='>'?a/2:i=='<'?a*2:i=='@'?a>>4|a<<4:a)&255},0)
```

Nested ternary operators map to instructions.

BITWISE AND is used to constrain our Number type to a single byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Forth (gforth), 217

```
: o over ; : x 0 begin key dup emit swap o 13 = if . exit else o 33 = if invert else o 62 = if 1 rshift else o 60 = if 1 lshift else o 64 = if dup 4 lshift swap 4 rshift or then then then then then nip 255 and again ;
```

Not as short as I had hoped but oh well. I'm sure this can be golfed further. There doesn't seem to be any alternatives to if/elseif :/

Formatted / ungolfed:

```
: x
  0 ( accumulator )
  begin
    key dup emit swap ( read char, print it and stash it away )
         over 13 = if . exit ( on newline, print accumulator and return. )
    else over 33 = if invert ( inversion )
    else over 62 = if 1 rshift ( shift 1 right )
    else over 60 = if 1 lshift ( shift 1 left )
    else over 64 = if dup 4 lshift swap 4 rshift or ( swap )
    then then then then then
    nip ( remove read character )
    255 and ( constrain accumulator to 1 byte after each step )
  again
;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Crystal, 139 bytes

```
def f x
b=0_u8
x.chars.each do|c|
b=case c
when'!'
~b
when'>'
b>>1
when'<'
b<<1
when'@'
b<<4|b>>4
else raise ""
end
end
puts b
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# 193**

```
void Main(){byte a=0;foreach(var c in Console.ReadLine()){if(c=='!')a=(byte)~a;if(c=='>')a=(byte)(a>>1);if(c=='<')a=(byte)(a<<1);if(c=='@')a=(byte)(((a&240)>>4)|((a&15)<<4));}Console.Write(a);}
```

Comment: Don't you need `using System;` or something like that to access `Console.ReadLine` and `Console.Write` without the `System.` prefix?

Comment: Also it seems to me that you shouldn't have to cast to `byte` for each operation but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 344 char

```
a=string.rep("0",8)
t=io.read()
f={["!"]=function()local s="";for j=1,8 do s=s..(a:sub(j,j)=="0"and"1"or"0") end;return s end,[">"]=function() return "0"..a:sub(1,7) end,["<"]=function()return a:sub(2,8).."0"end,["@"]=function()return a:sub(5,8)..a:sub(1,4)end}
for i=1,#t do a=(f[t:sub(i,i)]or function()return a end)()end
print(tonumber(a,2))
```

Inspired by @Beta Decay's use of a string accumulator, seeing as lua has no byte type. Could probably be golfed more by using fewer functions.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 194 bytes

```
b<-readline();A<-rep(0,8);s<-strsplit(b,"")[[1]];for(r in s){if(r=="!")A<-(A+1)%%2;if(r==">")A<-c(0,A)[1:length(A)];if(r=="<")A<-c(A,0)[-1];if(r=="@")A<-c(A[5:8],A[1:4])};print(sum(A*(2^(7:0))))
```

ungolfed

```
b <- readline()
A <- rep(0, 8) 
s <- strsplit(b, "")[[1]]
for (r in s) {
    if (r == "!")
        A <- (A + 1) %% 2
    if (r == ">")
        A <- c(0, A)[1:length(A)]
    if (r == "<")
        A <- c(A, 0)[-1]
    if (r == "@")
        A <- c(A[5:8], A[1:4])
}
print(sum(A*(2^(7:0))))
```

Comment: All the `<-` can be replaced by `=` here, thus reducing the code by 7 bytes. Additionally you might be able to replace the series of `if` statements by one call to `switch` (as in `A=switch(r,"!"=(A+1)%%2, ...)`)

Comment: The resulting `b=readline();A=rep(0,8);s=strsplit(b,"")[[1]];for(r in s)A=switch(r,"!"=(A+1)%%2,">"=c(0,A)[1:length(A)],"<"=c(A,0)[-1],"@"=c(A[5:8],A[1:4]),A);print(sum(A*(2^(7:0))))` is 167 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## RPL, 170.5 bytes

The input should be entered as a string on level 1.

```
\<< DEC 8 STWS \-> S 
    \<< #0d 1 S SIZE 
        FOR I "!><@" S I DUP SUB POS 1 + { \<< \>> NOT SR SL \<< DUP #16d / SWAP #16d * + \>> } SWAP GET EVAL NEXT \>> 
\>>
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 57 bytes

It's a start:

```
0{y+2*x}/(8#0){((~:;{-1_0,x};{1_ x,0};4!;{x})"!><@"?y)x}/
```

tested using Kona:

```
  f:0{y+2*x}/(8#0){((~:;{-1_0,x};{1_ x,0};4!;{x})"!><@"?y)x}/
...
  f'("!";"!>>";"!<@";"!nop!&6*!")
255 63 239 255
```

I might be able to do better in k5, but it's a complex series of tradeoffs- for example, converting binary to decimal is as easy as `2/`, but the behavior of `?` makes it harder to handle a default case for instruction lookup.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 189 bytes

```
<? $c='00000000';foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$a){$a=='!'&&$c=strtr($c,'01','10');$a=='<'&&$c=substr($c.'0',1);$a=='>'&&$c=substr('0'.$c,0,8);$a=='@'&&$c=substr($c.$c,4,8);}echo bindec($c);
```

It's not that it gonna beat many answers, it's only for practice

Answer (score 1):

## [HPPPL](http://www.hp-prime.de/en/category/6-downloads), <s>302</s> 294 bytes

```
#pragma mode(separator(.,;)integer(d8))EXPORT b()BEGIN print();local p,j,a;a:=#0d;INPUT({{p,[2]}});for j from 1 to dim(p)do c:=p(j);case if c==33 then a:=BITNOT(a)end if c==62 then a:=BITSR(a,1)end if c==60 then a:=BITSL(a,1)end if c==64 then a:=BITSL(a,4)+BITSR(a,4)end end;end;print(a*1);END;
```

Ungolfed:

```
// make sure integers are unsigned 8 bit decimal numbers
#pragma mode( separator(.,;) integer(d8) ) 
EXPORT b()
BEGIN
  print();
  local p,j,a;
  a:=#0d;                         // set a to integer value 0
  INPUT({{p,[2]}});               // open input dialog treating input as string ( type [2])
  for j from 1 to dim(p) do
    c:=p(j);
    case
      if c==33 then a:=BITNOT(a) end             // !
      if c==62 then a:=BITSR(a,1) end            // >
      if c==60 then a:=BITSL(a,1) end            // <
      if c==64 then a:=BITSL(a,4)+BITSR(a,4) end // @
    end;
  end;
  print(a*1); // converts to proper output by promoting to non integer format
              // print(a) would result in
              // #239:8d for 239 if the default bit size is not set to 8 bits decimal
              // indicating an 8 bit unsigned decimal integer, or
              // #239d if the default bit size is already set to 8 bits decimal

END;
```

[image: HPPPL Input command]

[image: HPPPL Output to Terminal]

This answer ensures that the HP Prime uses unsigned 8 bit integers even if the mode is set to e.g. 64 bits by the user. If the calculator is set up manually to using unsigned 8 bit decimal integers, then the `pragma` command can be omitted.
If the output does not need to follow the format strictly then the `a*1` at the end can simply be `a`. Multiplying the result by 1 just ensures the output does not follow the internal output for integer values.
The `print` command in line 4 can also be omitted if the terminal does not need to be cleared before printing out the result.
If passing the program as a string argument is allowed, then the `INPUT` command can be omitted as well.

This is the shortest version with input and proper output, without the pragma argument (if the calculator is set to Uint8 by default:

**243 bytes:**

```
EXPORT b()BEGIN local p,j,a;a:=#0d;INPUT({{p,[2]}});for j from 1 to dim(p)do c:=p(j);case if c=33 then a:=BITNOT(a)end if c=62 then a:=BITSR(a,1)end if c=60 then a:=BITSL(a,1)end if c=64 then a:=BITSL(a,4)+BITSR(a,4)end end;end;print(a*1);END;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 6, <s>96</s> 89 bytes

```
{my $a=0;$a=(+^*,*+<1,*+>1,{$_+<4+$_+>4},{$_})["!<>@".index($_)//4]($a)%256 for .comb;$a}
```

Old solution:

```
{my $a=0;$a=(255-*,*+<1+&255,*+>1,{$_+&15+<4+$_+>4},{$_})["!<>@".index($_)//4]($a)for .comb;$a}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 119 bytes

```cs
i=>{var a=0;foreach(var c in i){if(c=='!')a=~a;if(c=='>')a>>=1;if(c=='<')a<<=1;if(c=='@')a=a<<4|a>>4;a&=255;}return a;}
```

Other versions I tried, but need more bytes:

```cs
Func<string,int>C=i=>{var a=0;foreach(var c in i){switch(c){case'!':a=~a;break;case'<':a<<=1;break;case'>':a>>=1;break;case'@':a=a<<4|a>>4;break;}a&=255;}return a;};

// This is, despite having the worst score, my personal favourite :D
Func<string,int>D=i=>{var f=new Dictionary<char,Func<int,int>>{{'!',q=>~q},{'<',q=>q<<1},{'>',q=>q>>1},{'@',q=>q<<4|q>>4}};var a=0;foreach(var c in i)if(f.ContainsKey(c))a=f[c](a)&255;return a;};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7.3, 104 bytes

Having code in strings to be evaluated looks pretty dirty, but works :D

```
a=0
for c in raw_input():a=eval({'!':'~a','<':'a<<1','>':'a>>1','@':'a<<4|a>>4'}.get(c,'a'))&255
print a
```

Here's the output (and input actually..)

And yes, it's really running on a RaspberryPi :)

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 316 bytes

```
->,[>++++[<-------->-]<-[>>]<[>>>>+[->-<]>[-<+>]<<<]++++[<------->-]<+[>>]<[>>>>[->++<]>[-<+>]<<<]<--[>>]<[>>>>[->+>+<<]>>[->>--[--<->]<-<]>[[-]<<->>]<<[--<+>]<<<]<--[>>]<[>>>>[->+>+<<]>>[->>++++[-<++++>]<<]>[->+>+<<]>>[>++++[<---->-]>+<<]>>[-<<<<<<->>>>>>]<<<<<<[>++++[<---->-]>+<<]>>>[-<+>]<[-<<<+>>>]<<<<<]<,]>>>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY8xCkJBDETPso2F@bG0CnORkEIFQYSvCJ5/nUT9umDhFMtm5iWb3d92p/l4P5x7V0wOodz0JWiYOhDGAxCnYwFXE3pmMeBJy4cmLDLQBMcYQreuYKRqyrRecM5ilX3p/zGgViFJJRxD/vUvbrl0WUlRimf1m33/onpkocOmDDe9t/lybavtuj0A)

Explanation:

```
->, input to cell 1
[
>++++[<-------->-]<- sub 33= now will be 0 if invert instruction (cell 1)
[>>] if not move to cell 3
<[    runs if !
>>>>+[->-<]>[-<+>]<<<  invert cell 4 to cell 5 back to 4 end 2
]
now ends on cell 2 either way

++++[<------->-]<+ sub 27
[>>]
<[ runs if shl
>>>>[->++<] shl cell 4 to cell 5
>[-<+>]< back to 4
<< to 2
]
ends on 2

<-- sub 2
[>>]
<[    runs if shr (hard)
>>>>[->+>+<<] copy 4 to cell 5 and 6
>>[->>--[--<->]<-<] get evenness of 6 to 7
>[ if odd
[-] zero cell 7
<<->> sub cell 5
]
ends cell 7
<<[--<+>]<<< shr cell 5 to 4
]
ends cell 2 again

<-- sub 2
[>>]
<[ if @ (also very hard)
>>>>[->+>+<<] copy 4 to 5 and 6 (end on 4)
>>[->>++++[-<++++>]<<] mul cell 6 by 16 to 7
>[->+>+<<] copy 7 to 8 and 9
>>[>++++[<---->-]>+<<] div 9 by 16 to 11= chopping off upper bits
>>[-<<<<<<->>>>>>]<<<<<< sub 5 by 11
[>++++[<---->-]>+<<] div 5 by 16 to 7
>>>[-<+>] add 8 to 7
<[-<<<+>>>]<<< move 7 to 4
<<
]
end on 2 again

<,] end on 1

a ends up at cell 4

>>>. print
```

Answer (score 1):

## GBZ80 machine code, 37 bytes

As soon as I saw this challenge, I knew I had to do this for the Game Boy where this maps 1:1.

```
000000a5: af 47 2a a7 c8 fe 21 28 00 fe 3c 28 00 fe 3e 28  .G*...!(..<(..>(
000000b5: 00 fe 40 20 ed cb 30 18 e9 78 2f 18 e4 cb 20 18  ..@ ..0..x/... .
000000c5: e1 cb 38 18 dd                                   ..8..
```

Commented assembly (`rgbds` with `#` comments instead of `;`):

```python
        SECTION ".text",ROM0
        # input: null terminated string in HL
        # output: accumulator final value in B
func::
        # a = 0
        xor     a, a
.with_ld:
        # Save A to B so we can load the next byte from the tape.
        ld      b, a
        # Since not all instructions require the A register, we can skip the
        # ld by jumping here instead.
.no_ld:
        # load byte from HL and increment
        # a = *hl++
        ld      a, [hli]
        # and A against itself to check for zero
        and     a, a
        # return if null terminator
        ret     z
        # just a normal compare and branch chain
        cp      a, "!"
        jr      z, .cpl
        cp      a, "<"
        jr      z, .left
        cp      a, ">"
        jr      z, .right
        cp      a, "@"
        # comment char, skip without ld
        jr      nz, .no_ld
        # b = (b >> 4) | (b << 4)
        swap    b
        jr      .no_ld
.cpl:
        # we need to use A for CPL
        ld      a, b
        # a = ~a
        cpl
        jr      .with_ld
.left:
        # b <<= 1
        sla     b
        jr      .no_ld
.right:
        # b >>= 1
        srl     b
        jr      .no_ld
```

Here is a version which prints directly using `printf` (SDCC ABI), satisfying the "must print" requirement (which I don't enjoy doing), 53 bytes

`00 00` represents unlinked placeholders for the string below and `_printf`.

```
000000e4: af 4f 2a a7 28 00 fe 21 28 00 fe 3c 28 00 fe 3e  .O*.(..!(..<(..>
000000f4: 28 00 fe 40 20 ec cb 31 18 e8 79 2f 18 e3 cb 21  (..@ ..1..y/...!
00000104: 18 e0 cb 39 18 dc 47 c5 21 00 00 e5 cd 00 00 e8  ...9..G.!.......
00000114: 04 c9 25 75 00                                   ..%u.
```

The only differences is that it uses `c` instead of `b` and adds a call to `printf`.

```python
        # .area _BASE
        SECTION ".text", ROM0
        # input: null terminated string in HL
        # output: decimal printed with printf
func::
        # a = 0
        xor     a, a
.with_ld:
        # save A to C
        ld      c, a
        # since not all instructions require the A register, we can skip the
        # ld by jumping here.
.no_ld:
        # a = *hli++
        ld      a, [hli]
        # and a, a is better than cp a, 0
        and     a, a
        # return if null terminator
        jr      z, .print
        # just a normal compare and branch chain
        cp      a, "!"
        jr      z, .cpl
        cp      a, "<"
        jr      z, .left
        cp      a, ">"
        jr      z, .right
        cp      a, "@"
        # comment char, skip without ld
        jr      nz, .no_ld
        # c = (c >> 4) | (c << 4)
        swap    c
        jr      .no_ld
.cpl:
        # we need to use A for CPL
        ld      a, c
        # a = ~a
        cpl
        jr      .with_ld
.left:
        # c <<= 1
        sla     c
        jr      .no_ld
.right:
        # c >>= 1
        srl     c
        jr      .no_ld
.print:
        # zero extend bc
        # a is known to be zero
        ld      b, a
        # SDCC uses cdecl
        push    bc
        # "%u"
        ld      hl, .str
        push    hl
        # printf("%u", (u16)result);
        call    _printf
        # restore stack and return
        add     sp, 4
        ret
.str:
        db "%u"
        db 0
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 98 bytes

```powershell
switch($args){!{[byte]$a=-bnot$a-band255}`<{$a=$a-shl1}`>{$a=$a-shr1}`@{$a=($a-shl4)+($a-shr4)}}$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1dT4MwFIbv@RUH0myg9MJ9JSaDNDF6q3GXy@JK18kMUmxLpsH@diwUN85Vz/O@52klzlyqnBcFZkLyFh2TplXnk2Z5iKh8V1HjN9vsR/MdognOSqERxRktD7Pl0uzXjaUWqLy4M/v0skm7kW4LXbiIbt1LLiJjEG2N55HQAzsxkHDqT2OwwuhCAj9NgxhW8zFaE4tm8/sxK0XlT1Y3fjAIIviFJyEfKcvxc/bBmYamryPF5KnSMSD@XVnMD5AAenOZ5KoutAUTdATimn2yfdk81EqLT@faESfrZlMzxpXqLMM55l9X@7XX27rayNvN6/@nw30fGM@0fw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), 106 bytes

```
Ì¢RGÏCCHçP®óëÊR>hñãåPLD¯[¼ùbë×ZÙ]nSÅ¸␝«¶òëêl%!}yn␅␏APC>|PU1ó␚jPM/|PU1ãÜÏ␔ç[HOPCçÏ¿fSOSCn␅␏APC}ÌùNu¸␔>÷SGCIóå*ï]CCHùóçÏSTSÀ␛á␋çPAD␀␀ÿ
```

<sup>due to lack of unicode representations for c1 control characters, they have been replaced by their superscripted abbreviations</sup>

Decompressed:

```
f(J$>>)g(+^>^)$>4<<>,.^[^>,.^]5Y.[J<-`;+[<]>S0J!>^-`(>>>>$>1S*</>$<=f<)g-`(>>>~f)g-`(>>}f>)g-`(>{f>>)+^]J>>>>>'@␍x!><␀␀
```