# Create a 'calculator interpreter'

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

Your task is to create an interpreter for a calculator. It has to parse commands like `5 + 5` and return the answer.

It has to be able to add, subtract, multiply, and divide. The interpreter only needs to accept two numbers (ex. `9 * 5` and `3 + 3`)

The interpreter will take input from a console/whatever, not a file.

**`Eval` isn't allowed**

---

**Examples:**

Input: `5 * 5`

Output: `25`

---

Input: `8 / 2`

Output: `4`

---

## Bonus

If you're really bored you can add these to the interpreter, if you'd like:

**Simple mathematical functions** like `sqrt`.

**Make the interpreter be able to accept more than two numbers** (ex. `55 + 55`)

Comment: Only cursory check, but duplicate? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/568/basic-calculator If not, I think you should quantify the bonus.

Comment: I'd almost say this is a dupe of [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/568/basic-calculator), but at the same time I feel that accepting only two numbers might make a difference. Either way, even if this isn't a dupe, the spec needs a bit more fleshing out: 1) Is `eval` allowed? 2) Can numbers be more than one digit?

Comment: What should `8 / 3` print?

Comment: Does the bonus have a byte value/% taken off the byte count?

Comment: By the way, we have a [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140) where you can post challenge ideas to get feedback from communinity before "going live".

Comment: This challenge would of gotten much further by disallowing eval. Most languages have build-in support for calculations

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the tip, I'll try it out next time I post something...

Comment: @Sp3000 Eval isn't allowed

Comment: @Dennis Response to your first comment: It should print 2.6, I guess

Comment: @Sp300 They don't have to be more than one digit, but you can add that if you're bored.

Answer (score 2):

**Perl, <s>10</s> 8 chars**

I hope this is not cheating ;)

8 chars (7 chars code + 1 for -p): Thanks to Dennis

```
perl -pe '$_=eval'
```

10 chars:

```
say eval<>
```

Takes input from STDIN and needs `perl v5.10` and above.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>10</s> 4 bytes

Anonymous function.

```
eval
```

Comment: `eval` is already assignable (e.g., `f=eval`), so I think you can claim a 4 byte solution.

Comment: Couldn't this technically be zero bytes? Just say 'call the function with the name `eval` to get the answer', the same way you could normally say 'call the function `f`'.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 1 byte

```
Q
```

For some reason, multiplication and division don't work in the online interpreter. The [Python interpreter](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth) behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2):

### ><>, 14 Bytes

Thanks @Sp3000 for saving 2 bytes

Quick, but kinda cool solution. Probably not an ideal golf, but utilizes an interesting feature of ><>.

```
<v ip02ii
n<,;
```

Receives input through the numerical interpretation of ascii characters (i.e. a is 97). It places the second character read (the operator) in the space after `<v`. Because dividing in ><> uses `,`, not `/`, I make use of the fact that `/` reflects the pointer to accommodate for that case.

Alternate solution if that's invalid (+4 Bytes):

```
<v %cip02i%ci
n<,;
```

For this we just take mod 12 (`c` pushes 12) of the input since `0` is 48 and there are only 10 characters.

If `,` could be used in place of `/`, this would be a lot shorter (something like `ii60pi n;` or `ic%ia0pic% n;`)

Golf suggestions gladly welcome -- I'm rather tired right now.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether the OP intended to allow `eval`-like submissions, but in any case the last line can just be `n<,;`

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 4 bytes  (or 0 bytes)

```
eval s
```

Pretty simple really. MATLAB will evaluate the string `s` you pass it, and voila. For example the following operators work:  `* / + - ^ sqrt() min() max()`. Well pretty much anything that you can think of.

Heck you can even print `Hello World!` if you want - `eval 'disp(''Hello World!'')'`.

To be honest given that MATLAB is already a calculator, you can call it `0` if you omit eval and simply type in the string:

```
>> 8/2
ans =
     4
```