# Create a working Stack

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, stack

Your mission, if you choose to accept it, is to create a stack that can do basic math operations.

**Explanation:**
Your stack must be able to do basic arithmetic (`+-*/`) and must support normal base 10 numbers (`0123456879`); numbers will only be one character long.

**Programming:**
Input from stdin will be loaded as a *program*. After the program has finished running, the contents of the stack will be printed with no spaces in between after the program runs.

Each character in the program does a different thing to the stack:

- A number will push itself
- A math operation will take the top two numbers on the stack and push the output.

**Example I/O:**

Input:

```
45+
```

Output:

```
9
```

Input:

```
235234
```

Output:

```
235234
```

Input:

```
566*+
```

Output:

```
41
```

Input:

```
243+-
```

Output:

```
-5
```

Input:

```
78+243+-
```

Output:

```
15-5
```

Division is shown as a integer if it has `.0`:

Input:

```
63/
```

Output:

```
2
```

Repeating Decimals are cut off at 2 places:

Input:

```
43/
```

Output:

```
1.33
```

**Rules**:

- You stack must have a length of least 128.
- Your stack must be double/float based.
- No eval-ing!

**Scoring:**
Your score is you byte count with a couple modifiers.

- x`0.9` if you include mod (`%`) and pow (`^`).
- x`0.8` if you parse numbers in base 36 (`0-9A-Z`).
- x`0.7` if you parse strings (each character of the string will be pushed as separate numbers)

  - `"Hi"` pushes `72` and `105`, which will output `72105`.

Comment: [Duplicate?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/221/8478)

Comment: Is there another stack question? Everything I found related to SE. @MartinBüttner

Comment: @AlexA. Yes, the input is the program.

Comment: @phase My comment was a link to another question which asks almost the same. The differences are the bonuses and that the other question doesn't read individual digits but entire (signed floating-point) numbers, which is why I didn't use my mod hammer to close it.

Comment: Ouch, I forgot I had [tag:code-golf] mod hammer.  Well if @MartinBüttner thinks its a dup too, then I think this is the right thing to do here.