# Interpret StackyMath!

Tags: code-golf, math, interpreter, stack

*Time for you to implement my new stack based language! It's called StackyMath. This will be a stack based language with 8 operations on the stack and ways to add numbers to the stack.*

#### List of operations:

- `/`: Division. Performed on the top 2 numbers of the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack.
- `*`: Multiplication. Performed on the top 2 numbers of the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack
- `-`: Subtraction. Performed on the top 2 numbers of the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack
- `+`: Addition. Performed on the top 2 numbers of the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack
- `^`: Exponentiation. Performed on the top 2 numbers of the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack
- `%`: Modulo. Performed on the top 2 numbers of the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack
- `!`: Factorial. Performed on the top number on the stack. Pushes the result back on the stack
- `D`: Duplicate the top number on the stack

#### Operations defined in pseudo code:

- `/`: `push(pop divided by pop)`
- `*`: `push(pop times pop)`
- `-`: `push(pop minus pop)`
- `+`: `push(pop plus pop)`
- `^`: `push(pop to the pop)`
- `%`: `push(pop mod pop)`
- `!`: `push(factorial pop)`
- `D`: `t = pop; push(t); push(t)`

#### How to push numbers to the stack:

Adding numbers to the stack is easy, just put the raw number in your program where you need it. If you need to put multiple numbers on the stack you can separate them with a comma (`,`). Your program will not need to process `-` numbers in the input, If the user wants one they should push the number they want negated, zero, and `-`. Numbers in the input of the program are also constrained to positive integers.

#### Input:

Your program should take the input on the command line, or from std in. Input will only consist of numbers (no scientific notation or decimals) delimited by `,` as needed, and the operations defined above.

#### Output:

Your program should print the number on the top of the stack.

Error cases:

- If the program tries to over-pop the stack, you should print `StackUnderflowException!!!` .
- If you have division by zero, print `DivisionByZeroException!!!`
- If a number that exceeds 64-bits, either while executing the program or processing a number in the input, print `NumberOverflowException!!!`
- If somehow you get a negative number on the top of the stack and you need to do a factorial, print `NegativeFactorialException!!!`
- If you have a floating point number on the tops of the stack and the next operation is factorial, print `FloatingFactorialException!!!`
- If no numbers are on the stack when the program exits (i.e. the program was empty) print `EmptyProgram!!!`

#### Notes:

- All error output to should got yo std err or closest equivalent.
- All numbers are constrained to 64-bit floating point.

Example programs:

```
50,47*                 -> 2350
50,47/                 -> 0.94
100,8!                 -> 40320  
100D*                  -> 10000
!                      -> StackUnderflowException!!!
5,2/!                  -> FloatingFactorialException!!!  
4,3!2*/                -> 3 
654,489,48,43/5*7D+-*% -> 77.68749999999909
                       -> EmptyProgram!!!
```

(I can add more if needed)

Comment: If it weren't for the Error cases, [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) could do this naturally (except converting `!` to `F`).

Comment: I figured, that's partly why I included them.

Comment: Yours is somewhat broader in scope, though it may be arguable that its a duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221/reverse-polish-notation

Comment: Wow, I forgot about that one. But I don't think they are dupes since you have to process errors and more operators are defined in mine.

Comment: `654,489,48,43/5*7D+-*%` should return `77.6875`. (`43/48*5-(7+7)` should be `(7+7)-43/48*5`)

Comment: Aww crap. Quite right, I messed it up. Fixing now.

Comment: Is it fine if we throw an exception with the correct text? Example: `throw 'EmptyProgram!!!';`

Comment: Shoulda thought of that. No, you can't. This may seem arbitrary but kinda the idea is to create your own language with its own exceptions, you don't want to see the interpreter throwing exceptions.

Comment: Does that mean my answer is invalid? I designed it to be run without needing a console, so the error message is displayed, but if you looked at the console you would see that it threw an exception also.

Comment: No, I think its fine. Just as long as the user can't see it by default.

Comment: In the requirement you only mentioned that in case of error a message has to be printed to STDERR. However your [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65588) also exits in case of error. Is exiting mandatory or optional?

Comment: Optional. I did it because exiting was the shortest way to stop the program. I didn't want to continue processing the program if it has errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ruby, <s>412</s> <s>410</s> <s>404</s> <s>392</s> <s>380</s> 377 characters

```ruby
def e m,x='Exception';warn m+x+?!*3;exit;end
def o;e'StackUnderflow'if$*==[];$*.pop;end
u=->n{e'DivisionByZero'if n.infinite?;e'NumberOverflow'if n>2**64;$*<<n}
f=->n{e'NegativeFactorial'if n<0;e'FloatingFactorial'if n.to_i<n;n<2?1:f[n-1]*n}
gets.gsub(/(\d+)|([+*\/%^-])|(!)|D/){$1?u[$1.to_f]:$2?u[eval"o#{$2>?A?:**:$2}o"]:$3?u[f[o]]:u[x=o]+u[x]}
e'EmptyProgram',''if$*==[]
p o
```

This is regular precision version using `Float`. The result precision is as in the sample code, but numeric overflow detection is not exact.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby StackyMath.rb <<< '654,489,48,43/5*7D+-*%'
77.68749999999909
```

### Ruby, <s>378</s> 377 characters

```ruby
def e m,x='Exception';warn m+x+?!*3;exit;end
def o;e'StackUnderflow'if$*==[];$*.pop;end
u=->n{e'NumberOverflow'if n>2**64;$*<<n}
f=->n{e'NegativeFactorial'if n<0;e'FloatingFactorial'if n.to_i<n;n<2?1:f[n-1]*n}
gets.gsub(/(\d+)|([+*\/%^-])|(!)|D/){$1?u[Rational$1]:$2?u[eval"o#{$2>?A?:**:$2}o"]:$3?u[f[o]]:u[x=o]+u[x]}rescue e'DivisionByZero'
e'EmptyProgram',''if$*==[]
p o.to_f
```

This is high precision version using `Rational`. The result precision is not always the same as in the sample code, but numeric overflow detection is exact.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby StackyMath-hi.rb <<< '654,489,48,43/5*7D+-*%'
77.6875
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 430 bytes

422 bytes with ES7 by changing `Math.pow(2,2)` to `2**2`

```js
e=m=>{throw alert(m)};u=prompt();u?alert(eval('u.match(/\\d+|[^,]/g).map(o=>s.push(t=o=="/"?(b=p(a=2))?a/b:e`DivisionByZero43*"?2*23-"?2-23+"?2+23%"?2%23^"?Math.pow(2,2)3D"?s.push(r=2)&&r3!"?eval("for(r=i=2;i<0?e`Negative54:i%1?e`Floating54:--i;)r*=i;r"):+o)&&t==Infinity&&e`NumberOverflow4,s=[],p=_=>s.length?s.pop():e`StackUnderflow4);t'.replace(/[2-5]/g,x=>[,,'p()',':o=="','Exception!!!`','Factorial'][x]))):e`EmptyProgram!!!`
```

### Explanation

Uses `eval` to replace certain common phrases. Ungolfed and without the `eval` it looks like this:

```js
e=m=>{throw alert(m)};                           // e = throw error, alert displays
                                                 //     message, throw stops execution
u=prompt();                                      // u = received input
u?alert(                                         // display the result
  u.match(/\d+|[^,]/g)                           // get array of numbers and operators
    .map(o=>                                     // iterate over operators
      s.push(t=                                  // t = last pushed value

        // Execute operator
        o=="/"?(b=p(a=p()))?a/b:                 // make sure argument B is not 0
          e`DivisionByZeroException!!!`:
        o=="*"?p()*p():
        o=="-"?p()-p():
        o=="+"?p()+p():
        o=="%"?p()%p():
        o=="^"?Math.pow(p(),p()):
        o=="D"?s.push(r=p())&&r:
        o=="!"?eval("                            // eval to enable for loop in ternary
          for(                                   // no factorial in JS so do this manually
            r=i=p();
            i<0?e`NegativeFactorialException!!!` // check for errors
              :i%1?
                e`FloatingFactorialException!!!`
                :--i;
          )
            r*=i;
          r"):                                   // return r
        +o                                       // if not an operator cast as a number
      )&&t==Infinity&&                           // JS turns anything over 64 bit float
        e`NumberOverflowException!!!`,           //     max value into Infinity
      s=[],                                      // s = stack array
      p=_=>s.length?s.pop():                     // p = check stack then pop
        e`StackUnderflowException!!!`
    )&&t                                         // return top stack element
  ):e`EmptyProgram!!!`                           // error if input length is 0
```

Comment: If you want to upgrade to ES7, you could use the [ES7 exponentiation operator](https://github.com/hemanth/es7-features#exponentiation-operator) to replace `Math.pow(p(),p())` with `p()**p()`.

Comment: @usandfriends I was thinking about it, but it meant that it would not work in my browser so I left it out. :P I'll add a note saying that.

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 718 bytes. *Fore!*

May as well post my impl golfed. Meet my big wall of code:

```groovy
g='Exception!!!'
a={System.err.print(it);System.exit(1)}
b=new Stack()
c={b.push(it)}
v=2d**64d
d={b.pop()}
e={if(b.size()<it)a('StackUnderflow'+g)}
f={a('NumberOverflow'+g)}
h={e(2)
c(Eval.xy(d(),d(),"x$it y"))
if(b.peek()>v)f()}
k={i->if(i<0)a('NegativeFactorial'+g)
if(Math.abs(i-(i as long))>1E-6)a('FloatingFactorial'+g)
(2..i).inject{x,y->(v/x<y)?f():x*y}}
l=['/':{e(2)
m=d()
n=d()
if(n==0)a('DivisionByZero'+g)
c(m/n)},'!':{e(1)
c(k(d()))},'D':{e(1)
c(b.peek())}]
System.in.newReader().readLine().findAll(~/\d+|[^,]/).each{x->if(x.matches(/\d+/))try{c(x as double)}catch(Exception e){f()}
else if("+-*%^".contains(x))h(x.replace('^','**'))
else l[x]()}
if(b){o=d()
if(Double.isInfinite(o))f()
println o}else a('EmptyProgram!!!')
```

Ungolfed:

```groovy
error = {System.err.print(it);System.exit(1)}

stack = new Stack()
maxVal = 2d**64d

push = {stack.push(it)}
pop = {stack.pop()}

checkAtLeast = {if (stack.size() < it) error('StackUnderflow'+exception)}
numberOverflow = {error('NumberOverflow'+exception)}

exception = 'Exception!!!'

def dArgOp(i) {
    checkAtLeast(2)
    push(Eval.xy(pop(), pop(), "x$i y"))
    if(stack.peek() > maxVal) numberOverflow
}

factorial = {i->
    if (i < 0)
        error('NegativeFactorial'+exception)
    if (Math.abs(i - (i as long)) > 1E-6)
        error('FloatingFactorial'+exception)
    (2..i).inject {acc, it ->
        (maxVal/acc < it)?numberOverflow():acc*it
    }
}

ops = [
'/' : {
    checkAtLeast(2)
    first = pop()
    second = pop()
    if (second == 0)
        error('DivisionByZero'+exception)
    push(first / second)
},
'!' : {
    checkAtLeast(1)
    push(factorial(pop()))
},
'D' : {
    checkAtLeast(1)
    push(stack.peek())
}]

input = System.in.newReader().readLine()
tokens = input.findAll(~/\d+|[^,]/)

tokens.each {
    print "current token: $it  \t stack before eval: $stack "
    if (it.matches(/\d+/))
        try {
            push(it as double)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            numberOverflow()
        }

    else if ("+-*%^".contains(it))
        dArgOp(it.replace('^','**'))
    else
        ops[it]()
    println "result: ${stack.peek()}"
}

if (stack) {
    top = pop()
    if (Double.isInfinite(top))
        numberOverflow()
    println top
} else
    error('EmptyProgram!!!')
```

Edit 1: save ~15 bytes thanks to @Doorknob
Edit 2: drop ~130 bytes with a few more tricks

Comment: I don't know Groovy, but you seem to have lots of unnecessary whitespace. For example, around operators, after `for`/`if`, etc

Comment: Whoops, just noticed many more places to remove whitespace. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can use `System.in.text` instead of `System.in.newReader().readLine()`.

Comment: Not really. `.text` is greedy and as long as data in in the reader, it won't return.

Comment: Right, but this is code-golf. It's not a big deal if people have to type Control-D after their input.

Comment: Right, forgot about Ctrl-D. I almost never use the command line. It doesn't matter since I will remove this shortly in favor of the python answer I'm working on.

Comment: @quartata as it turns out `my skills + python + this challenge` is more than 900 bytes, so I plan to keep this one. Oh and for some reason Ctrl-D quits the process, not end the std in. Do you use OSX or lunix?

Comment: I use Linux. I'm not sure why Ctrl-D would quit the process (it just means EOF). Try giving your input like this: `groovy script <<< INPUT`

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Perhaps it's a bash feature.

Comment: Does it require a specific version of Groovy? The 1.8.6 I use raises exception on factorial: “groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.lang.ObjectRange.inject()”.

Comment: It looks like you would need [1.8.7 min](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) (from the docs) but I'm not sure. I am using groovy 2.4.5 right now.

Comment: Not getting NumberOverflowException when calculating `65,2^` is also a version difference?

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on when I do that. It would seem that I'm using big decimal instead of double.... I'll see if I can fix that soon.

Comment: Quite odd. It _looks_ like I'm using double (`getClass().getSimpleName()` is `Double`) but increasing the value has no effect. Is double replaced with `BigDecimal` in groovy?

Comment: @manatwork Weird, Double has `Double.MAX_EXPONENT`, set to `1023`. So `2d**1024d` is `Infinity`, but `2d**64d` is just fine...

Comment: If you ask me, that 64 bit thing is the requirement's issue. ;) In a certain degree it should appear in most of the languages. (For my Ruby solution there would be a trick to use `Rational` instead, but then you get higher precision for the result too, not just the error checking. I mean, `654,489,48,43/5*7D+-*%` would result 77.6875.)

Comment: I'm not sure I can fix it now, It's a little late to change the question ;) I will go ahead and fix my answer though.

Comment: @manatwork That should fix it. Thanks for catching that problem.

Comment: Now it works like in Ruby: `64,2^1000+` passes and gets calculated, `64,2^10000+` raises the exception. I strongly believe there is no better solution given the machine's internal floating point representation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy), <s>298</s> <s>348</s> 392 bytes

Although Candy is stack based, I'm not sure that really helped...

```
&{|"EmptyProgram!!!\n"(;).}(=bYZay0=zx4k"!%*+,-/D^"(iYe{Z=x})aYb=z=ya=X{Y{cZ0=yza}b212202221(i=ZXe{y})a0=zcY0j{XjZ{|D1b#64R(=c2*)c>{b"NumberOverFlow"(;)i}}|i}aZ{(=)"Exception!!!\n"(;).}0=yz|A#48-Z#10*+=z1=y})c?(=).@0&<{1|b"StackUnderflow"(;)c0}.@1~ALe{A0<{b"Negative"(;)i|1bAR(=cA*)}|b"Floating"(;)i}Z{b"Factorial"(;)}.@2W%.@3*.@4+@5.@6W-.@7WD{/|b"DivisionByZero"(;)i}.@8~A.@9=xK=y=1bA_(cX*).
```

Formatted a bit reveals a bit of structure:

```
&{|"EmptyProgram!!!\n"(;).}
(=bYZay0=zx4k
  "!%*+,-/D^"
  (iYe{Z=x})
  aYb=z=ya=X
  {
    Y{cZ0=yza}b
    212202221(i=ZXe{y})
    a0=zcY0j
    {XjZ{|D1b#64R(=c2*)c>{b"NumberOverFlow"(;)i}}|i}
    aZ{(=)"Exception!!!\n"(;).}
    0=yz|A#48-Z#10*+=z1=y
  }
)c?(=).
@0&<{1|b"StackUnderflow"(;)c0}.
@1~ALe{A0<{b"Negative"(;)i|1bAR(=cA*)}|b"Floating"(;)i}Z{"Factorial"(;)}.
@2W%.@3*.@4+@5.@6W-.@7WD{/|"DivisionByZero"(;)i}.@8~A.@9=xK=y=1bA_(cX*).
```

The actual math occurs on the last two lines.  It's driven there by a jump table on the third line.

Comment: Dang, I see that I missed DivisionByZero, NegativeFactorial, and Overflow.  I was just looking at the test cases!

Comment: Wow, this is cool. I just might need to look up candy.

Comment: I'm still working on how exactly to _define_ overflow.

Comment: Actually I had the same problem in my answer. See the comments below my answer.

Comment: Fixed the Overflow now.  I used the same approach as the Ruby, which is just to compare to 2^64 at the end of each operation.