# Solving Reverse Polish Notation with GolfScript and Eval Function

Tags: code-golf, tips, golfscript

I am exploring a unique approach to the classic problem of [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) on [code.golf](https://code.golf/). Unlike the conventional solutions, my focus lies on leveraging the `eval` function in GolfScript. This twist was inspired by a comment in a related [thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221/reverse-polish-notation), where the absence of `eval` was deemed a limitation.

> "It's a shame no eval is allowed, otherwise the GolfScript solution is 1 character: ~. :-P" – C. K. Young

Despite being intrigued by the idea of solving the problem with minimal characters, I'm encountering challenges in implementing the solution. The specifications, as outlined on [code.golf](https://code.golf/reverse-polish-notation#golfscript), involve computing a list of arguments in polish notation stored in the stack `n`. The goal is to evaluate and print the result of each expression on a separate line. The expected results are non-negative integers not exceeding 32,767, with guaranteed exact integer results for division.

I am currently attempting a concise GolfScript solution using the `n*` stack initialization for arguments. Following C. K. Young's hint, I have tried variations like `~n*` and `n*~` to no avail. I believe the solution is close but needs some expert insight to refine it further.

If you are well-versed in GolfScript or have experience with similar challenges, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. My goal is to gain a deeper understanding of this fascinating language and unlock the potential of the `eval` function within the constraints of the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges SE. I have made a minor edit to your post to fit some common conventions for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The specifications [...] involve computing a list of arguments in polish notation stored in the stack `n`.

I think you are slightly misunderstanding the code.golf specification. The input is not a variable `n`, but rather a list of strings already present on the stack when the program begins.

In GolfScript, there is a variable called `n`, but it is not the input to the program; it is a string containing a single newline.

Your attempt `~n*` is pretty close. The problem is that `~` only does `eval` if its argument—the top of the stack—is a string. In this case, the top of the stack is actually a list of strings.

Therefore, you have to use the map `%` function to loop over each element of the list:

```
{~}%
```

Once we have this, we need to join the results on newlines. We can simply do:

```
{~}%n*
```

As I think you figured out already, `n*` means join (`*`) on newlines (`n`).

However, if we use the function each (`/`) instead of map (`%`), we can just push the newline to the stack during each iteration, saving a byte:

```
{~n}/
```

When a GolfScript program has finished execution, the entire stack is printed without a seperator. Here, each `eval`'d result is followed by a newline on the stack, which does the equivalent of joining the list on newlines.

Try the final program on [TIO.run](https://tio.run/##RVbbjiw1DHyfr4jO46xa40viJN@DBEJCBwS8Ifj1PVXVmUWrzk7n4tjlcrl/@f23n//66c9f//j789vYLduzxZwzWnpbc@D1ah/N@57Zwmd7tdEx8dECu2ti3Zuvwk6Pvb2NWonVCwvWwoonPvg85s421554TRirHC3DZL4v2pxRRcOb06FzNca9I2DNeNJXLy1Z81p94Lfn3B3vT83St9cjI7Jl980h5M5skTFhOW3CZ59lrW@cv/CXHmPCeV@4yrGb007j07rpV@KIteGbd2IhemJ1Kjq8rlWrzUTAIQyXpqcJIdOuHLjyJe/hTneep3ccnU7o5qe2vB4EZfF0zllthSIVQvTMjalKn8DcN9J1YKenSMSI23s@yB0hi5ipdEaNTkjCO4B2oEGveDFdQRxnpJ9RfRcTzLEcKbxaB2pYUR5o1qZSxByDITkRdAZJIwcYUoAV42TwqQdBjTtnrqNIV2@Fa8656wE7aa4XbBrgyCZqmQf@7MmjA2EMpIQYLuUZaRr0aHsoB48sJgtBeiTCAEZTXsmP6FGI0nGzu0L2vdJaKtRhluIHmWeYRm30FIabeO@@HBctwkk/o6/qZ@TVdd/EEtllQiC2j/v2O3Lv@hHWM7WcsTVtU@S@N2WiJEHFwXNw5MYuMsVgP/G8BIBy@egG/gTuBXTbGfYYMQ@8wHLEu7aVFm/Ta8iOfrwOEwN8J5oxFk4wqigLIT9Ft7y3paGaRG8FPIcfMsOjh1fkauIGjviukkX8nTo3YuZUmxmGErQBSmNcSxsHD5OI6xQPn0DF5hmvN9HMOKfxkhSAHBMIQwxQJW9ZuW60Htb2SCkVEjB7kdGgyS5SRuPrNrL2Bj9y5J17H29L5DYWtkrewEBUMn1OW4UI3AffPE1klZKVAYbotpdSsbkAy9S5kfPUt4Fe8ACuM78d5is7Dow15WPo7pfSpGrB7dA647pTWi9oLbjBKncjPTtqEnyJ@9bRz2HvFKXqnSlZ7l2zIDv0cxon57C7L0BGVlv06UM1sUZJRjaoC9M@8lQBeF/hjxi24GnU3BTKoVSiMHbn/r7oUPGe0ZN1X1V3sUEcFlEdPk@qeGFuwnA9kAxoxSBJwZUttDo8U1PqSdITP50Lgy22lgWIyVnGgQEsRWmzC8RQTqLWyShK7QZmGlkncTNR1P7vL0doHDDGKrgJB9glPJl@Fbct3@/eAAfFNzB5dFGVRYdxdMpFUv6hxuieC/dphQxC80AKiFUuVUDed7A/9v42RFMIgLwnAQAACu2Q6zo1/vz6O4SRZ89TSXc6n1/74OiK6C0rQ9GnIYt0AK0QMUCKULsFVCExebert27rP1CoEI1cFLnRc2GX6DqpkSuOWmUnn@hIffa3jt7lCb0COpWkPM3VACHZDCacu6SDEpzZ1Qx5/3RVEDjiKlXwWq0InwqSEu7fZ6/2pz5nUAWkp4OT3A7NYD@Oue2rj93PcvE4xaqaRfptGJeuMeGP9DKQtyiAiIg9HErZ7RTsU45TQ8jmpHxpLEUOyoMJw9mXY45bxDyXgsI29WtQ1RHXPHmDiiL36JWdTXL2k0znHfgiIRCk40g/HzbPQwyoa7JnQ@9v3Ucvi1Bz3pswdMjwrVmbWpJlfE1oefHLQ5IFcaLzaK9DRhntNn0dfHx1BxVELMQ9zFlwfYSIbKEgVCKlbv3t@@vzn/@@//v6/PwB)!